# Строки и слова

Tags: строки, c++

Программа должна выводить, сколько раз каждое слово  встречается в строке, но этого не происходит. Вот код:

```
void main()
{   
    map <string,int>m;
    map<string,int>::iterator it;

    vector <string> v1;int n;int sum=1;
cout<<"size of vector"<<endl;
cin>>n;
cin.get();
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{   
         string str;
         getline(cin,str,'\n');
}
for(int i=0;i<v1.size();++i)
{   
         m[v1[i]]++;
}
for( it=m.begin();it!=m.end();++it)
{  
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second;
}
system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: @Роман Пономаренко, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Роман Пономаренко, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нигде не сохраняются считанные строки. Полагаю, нужно так.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str, '\n');
    v1.push_back(str);
    m.insert(std::make_pair(str, 0));
}
for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
    m[v1[i]]++;
}
```

**Обновление**

http://ideone.com/SPY4Nx  Тут всё работает

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, int> m;
    map<string, int>::iterator it;
    vector<string> v1;
    int n;
    int sum = 1;
    cout << "size of vector" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cin.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string str;
        getline(cin, str, '\n');
        v1.push_back(str);
        m.insert(std::make_pair(str, 0));

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
        m[v1[i]]++;
    }
    for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it -> first << " " << it -> second;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @iksuy изменил но вывод всё равно неправильный, вот фото http://screenshot.su/show.php?img=3185a3e29d3512d34a022c3ab46af64a.jpg

Comment: Обновил овтет

Comment: @iksuy спасибо

Comment: Чтобы подсчитать слова, [можно без дополнительного вектора обойтись, используя только одну `map`](http://hashcode.ru/questions/376531#376786).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посчитать слова, можно использовать `unordered_map`, которая более эффективна чем `map`, если кол-во слов большое (`O(1)` (амортизовано) против `O(log n)` для каждого слова).

Если каждая строка содержит ровно одно слово, то подсчитать слова совсем просто:

```
unordered_map<string, size_t> counter;
string line;
getline(cin, line); // read n and ignore it
while(getline(cin, line)) // count words
    ++counter[line];
```

Чтобы напечатать в порядке убывания частоты слов (самые встречаемые слова сначала) можно скопировать частоты в вектор и отсортировать его по частоте:

```
vector<pair<string,size_t>> v(begin(counter), end(counter));
sort(begin(v), end(v), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return a.second > b.second;
    });
for (const auto& p : v)
    cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
```

#### [Полный пример](http://ideone.com/piBeDE)

```
5
One
Two
Three
One
One
```

#### Вывод

```
One 3
Three 1
Two 1
```

Если нужно вывести слова в "алфавитном" (лексикографическом) порядке и частота слов небольшая и/или производительность не важна, то можно использовать просто `map` без `unordered_map` + `sort`:

```
/** Count words.

    One word per line.
    Print words in lexicographical order.

    To try:

      $ g++ -std=c++11 count-words-map.cpp && ./a.out <input
      One 3
      Three 1
      Two 1

*/
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    map<string, size_t> counter;
    string line;
    getline(cin, line); // read n and ignore it
    while(getline(cin, line)) // count words
        ++counter[line];

    if (!cin.eof())
        return 1; // I/O error

    // print words and their frequencies
    for (const auto& p : counter)
        cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
}
```

В данном случае [вывод (случайно) получается таким же](http://ideone.com/X0Qmmb) как и для `unordered_map`.

Comment: @jfs спасибо за совет.