# Читать строки из файла, пока они есть

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно в цикле читать слово из файла. Цикл должен работать до тех пор, пока в файле есть строки.
Читаю строки так:

```
std::ifstream val("val.txt"); 
char val2[16] ; 
val >> val2;
```

Comment: Ну давайте начнем. Как вы просто будете читать строки? Пока отложим в сторону "пока они есть". Как вы прочтете строку из файла?

Comment: Похож: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/290919/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0?rq=1 и тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74601/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0?rq=1

Comment: @VladSpirin Нужного ответа там нет.

Comment: В ответе вы не читаете, а пытаетесь вывести. И не строки, а слова :) Намекаю - посмотрите в сторону функции `getline`.

Comment: @Harry Как отследить момент, после которого уже не надо читать?

Comment: На всякий случай еще раз: вот так - `val >> val2;` - вы читаете **не строку, а слово**. Если вас устраивает чтение не по строкам, а по словам - можно и так. Но опасно - слово может быть длиннее, чем ваш буфер. Но опять же - **что возвращает** инструкция `val >> val2;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего автор пытался сказать, как проверить, закончился ли файл:

```
if(val.eof())
   break;
```

И да, читаете Вы слово, а не строку.

Comment: Вообще-то все куда проще - `while(val>>val2){...}`. А с проверкой `eof()` - вечная проблема, потому как ее начинают использовать как `while(!val.eof()){...}`, а потом сюда вопросы пишут, почему не работает...

Comment: @Harry, вроде бы в каждом учебнике пишут, что проверять следует после конца файла.

Comment: @Range: Что значит "проверять следует после конца файла"? Если мы уже "после конца файла", то зачем проверять? Это во-первых. Во-вторых, в С/С++ коде чтения файла обычно не должно быть прямых проверок на eof. Проверки на eof нужны только в коде обработки ошибочной ситуации - чтобы выяснить, что именно произошло.

Comment: @AnT объясняю, как это понял я.  Есть цикл для чтения строк из файла. Читаем строку, затем проверяем файл на конец, записываем строку куда-то в буфер. Т.е., при очередном считывании из файла в строку ничего не считается, т.к. файл кончится и последующая проверка выведет нас из цикла.

Comment: @Range: Ну то есть вы хотели сказать "проверять следует после чтения", а не ваше странное "проверять следует после конца файла". Но в общем случае это - неправильный подход. Вы сделали операцию чтения, после нее вдруг увидели статус eof. О чем это вам говорит? Прочиталось ли что либо вообще или нет? Как вы это выясните? Вот именно поэтому все операции чтения сами тем или иным образом возвращают статус успешности, который и надо проверять. А не eof.

Comment: @AnT вообще задумался, да, быть может и было что-то считано, а у нас уже eof. Городить кучу проверок явно лишнее. И спасибо за науку.

Answer (score 2):

Проверяйте на успешность каждую операцию чтения:

```
ifstream file("val.txt");
for (string word; file >> word; ) 
  ; // здесь что-то с word можно сделать
```

Цикл заканчивается когда произошла ошибка либо наступил конец файла. Никаких `file.eof()` нет в условии цикла. Только после цикла, после чтения имеет смысл вызвать `file.eof()`, чтобы узнать наступил ли конец файла. К примеру, чтобы [вернуть статус возврата из `main()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/377923/23044):

```
return !file.eof(); // успех, если дошли до конца файла
```

---

Для чтения строк [можно использовать `getline()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/376786/23044):

```
while(getline(cin, line)) // count words
    ++counter[line];

if (!cin.eof())
    return 1; // I/O error
```

Обратите внимание, возвращаемое значение `getline()` проверяется после каждого вызова, `cin.eof()` внутри цикла чтения не используется и вызывается после окончания чтения. Если конец файла не достигнут, то это считается ошибкой в этом случае.

---

Аналогично при неявных `>>`-операциях. К примеру, чтобы найти слово в файле, [можно использовать `istream_iterator<>`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/384839/23044):

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
istream_iterator<string> eof;
bool found = find(istream_iterator<string>(file), eof, word) != eof;
```

Снова, `file.eof()` при чтении файла не используется. Можно в конце [вызвать `.eof()` метод, чтобы узнать произошла ли ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/384839/23044):

```
int main() {
    ...
    return found ? 0 : (cin.eof() ? 1 : 2);
}
```

В этом случае, нулевой статус означает что слово найдено, а `cin.eof()` позволяет различить случаи когда слово не присутствует (возвращается `1`) от случая когда ошибка произошла (возвращается  `2`) -- как это `grep` утилита может делать.