# Не могу придумать условие конца бинарного файла

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо считать содержимое бинарного файла и с его помощью заполнить значениями список. Проблема в том что не могу придумать условия выхода из цикла while

```
void read_file_bin(DblList* list, int a[])
{
    FILE *File = fopen("list_read.dat", "rb");
    if(File)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(!EOF) //не работает
        {
            fread(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, File);
            pushBack(list, &a[i]); //вставить считанный элемент в список
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{cout << "Ошибка чтения бинарного файла!" << endl;}
    fclose(File);
}
```

Процедура записи в бинарный файл:

```
void write_file_bin(DblList* list)
{
    Node* tmp = list->head;
    FILE *File = fopen("list_write.dat", "wb");
    if (File)
    {
        while (tmp) //Пока по адресу на начало хоть что-то есть
        {
            fwrite(&tmp->value, sizeof(int), 1, File);
            tmp = tmp->next; //Указываем на следующий адрес из списка
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!" << endl;
    }
    fclose(File);
}
```

Comment: `while(!feof(File))`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а не надо ли там еще восклицательный знак? :-)

Comment: Оно будет работать по принципу "пока не закончился бинарный файл"?

Comment: @Vladimir, спасибо, верно подмечено, мой косяк...

Comment: @Trapezant, да, но условие выхода сработает только после того как будет попытка чтения за концом файла...

Comment: @ Vladimir,   восклицательный знак  или все таки логическое отрицание?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, мой комментарий был адресован человеку, который все правильно понял. Если для Вас "смайл" в конце предложения ничего не значит и Вы начисто лишены чувства юмора, то прошу прощения, что этим ввел Вас в заблуждение.

Comment: ```while(fread(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, File) == 1)
{
    pushBack(list, &a[i++]);
}```

Comment: @Vladimir,  вас возмущает  безобидный вопрос,  и после этого я лишен чувство юмора?  Вы задали вопрос, вас вежливо отблагодарили, я задал такого же рода вопрос, но с другим содержанием, вы возмущаетесь и переходите на грубость...

Comment: связанный вопрос [Читать строки из файла, пока они есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774231/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Вы, и не только Вы, совершаете одну и ту же ошибку. Даже если переделать условие на `while(!feof(File))`, то файл не будет считываться корректно. Такой подход концептуально не верен. Дело в том, что флаг `EOF` выставляется при попытке чтения за концом файла. Рассмотрим ситуацию, когда в файле три числа и как ваш цикл будет их считывать. Когда считалось последнее число, флаг `EOF` еще не выставлен, т.к. чтения за концом файла не было, поэтому получим следующее:

```
while(!feof(File))//Флаг EOF еще не выставлен, поэтому условие даст true
{
    fread(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, File);//Чтение не удалось, т.к. элементов нет, выставляется флаг EOF
    //Но у нас нет никаких проверок на успех чтения,
    //Поэтому код будет также выполнятся вне зависимости от ошибок чтения
    pushBack(list, &a[i]); //Какое число вставится в конец? Правильно - последнее успешно считанное
    i++;
}
```

То есть при таком подходе, создастся впечатление, что последний элемент считался дважды (собственно, форумы и сайты забиты подобными вопросами).

Каково может быть решение проблемы? Необходимо проверять флаг `EOF` уже ПОСЛЕ чтения, а не до:

```
while(true)
{
    fread(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, File);
    if (feof(File)) {//Если выставился EOF
        break;//Выходим из цикла
    }
    //...
}
```

Это будет работать, но решение тоже не очень хорошее. Вы читаете файл с помощью функции `fread`, а она в качестве результата возвращает количество считанных элементов. То есть мы можем проверить, все ли элементы считались или нет. Вы считываете за раз один элемент, поэтому в Вашем случае достаточно просто проверять успех чтения одного элемента:

```
//Выйдем из цикла, если один элемент не удалось считать
while(fread(&a[i], sizeof(int), 1, File) == 1)
{
    //...
}
```

Однако, стоит заметить, что чтение из бинарного файла лучше производить по возможности "пачкой", а не по одному элементу. Приведу пример чтения в вектор:

```
std::vector<int> read_binary_data(char const * path)
{
    auto close_file = [] (FILE * f) { fclose(f); };
    using SmartPtr_t = std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(close_file)>;
    SmartPtr_t file(fopen(path, "rb"), close_file);
    if(!file) {
        std::cerr << "File open failed\n";
        throw std::runtime_error("file open failed");
    }
    std::vector<int> result;    
    size_t const size = 256;//Считывать будем по 256 элементов за раз
    int buf[size];//Буфер под элементы
    size_t count = 0;//Количество успешно считанных элементов
    //если удалось считать хоть один элемент
    while ((count = fread(buf, sizeof(*buf), size, file.get())) != 0) {
        //то добавляем все считанные элементы в вектор
        result.insert(result.end(), buf, buf + count);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Конечно же, пример несколько упрощен, например, в нем отсутствует реакция на ошибки, не связанные окончанием файла, но, думаю, идея понятна.