# Не могу понять, почему цикл не завершается. По логике, когда будет достигнуть конец файла, а он есть, fefof() должен вернуть 1

Tags: c++, файлы

```
FILE*One= fopen("1.txt", "rb");                         // указывает на 1.txt
i=0;

    while(!feof(One)){
        if(i<a||i>number){
            fin_1.getline(buff,30);
            fout_2<<buff<<endl;
        }
        else{
            fin_3.getline(buff,30);
            fout_2<<buff<<endl;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Потому что вы читаете из одного потока (`fin_1`), а на достижение конца проверяете другой (`One`).

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы цикл все таки завершился. как из этих потоков сделать один?

Comment: `как из этих потоков сделать один` — выбираете какой-то из этих двух потоков и работаете только с ним. Второй при этом убираете как лишний.

Comment: близкий к заголовку вопрос: [Читать строки из файла, пока они есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774231/23044)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Правильное использование проверки конца файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/208074)

Comment: а Oneэто вообще не поток а ISO дескриптор файла

Answer (score 3):

Хотя вам подсказали, что вы читаете один файл, а проверяете другой... в любом случае проверка

```
while(!feof(file)) { ... }
```

неверна, потому что признак конца файла выставляется только **после неудачной попытки чтения за концом файла**.

Comment: когда feof имеет смысл вызывать выглядит как частый вопрос. Возможно имеет смысл в *одном месте* популярно с примерами изложить, а другие вопросы закрывать как дубликаты.

Comment: @jfs Имеет. Я когда-то такой вопрос-ответ написал было, налетела такая орава критиков, что счел за лучшее удалить и сам себе пообещал, что больше такого делать не буду. Делаю сегодня очередную (если не пройдет - уж точно последнюю....) попытку.

Comment: Стоит помнить, что правила для вопросов/ответов остаются те же, вне зависимости кто автор [Каков порядок создания канонических вопросов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7383/23044). Проблемы могут, конечно, и на пустом месте возникнуть. В таких случаях можно конкретный пример на Мете обсудить.