# Правильное использование проверки конца файла

Tags: c++, c, файлы, обработка-ошибок

При использовании кода

```
while(!feof(file))
{
    // Чтение из файла
}
```

в C или

```
while(!file.eof())
{
    // Чтение из файла
}
```

в C++ получаются неприятности - лишняя считанная строка, например. Почему? Как правильно проверить, что достигнут конец файла?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Читать строки из файла, пока они есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774231/23044)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Признак достижения конца файла выставляется только **после неудачной попытки чтения за его концом**. Поэтому, если в теле цикла нет проверки, успешно ли выполнено чтение из файла - последнее чтение окажется именно тем **неудачным** чтением, которое выставит признак достигнутого конца файла (а для вас это будет выглядеть как, например, еще раз считанная последняя строка, если она находилась в буфере для чтения).

Лучше в заголовке цикла `while` выполнять само чтение с проверкой - например, в программе на C это могло бы выглядеть как

```
while(fread(&data,sizeof(data),1,file)==1)
{
    // Обработка считанных данных
}

/* Или, скажем,
while(fgets(buf, bufsize, file)) { .... }
*/


if (feof(file)) // Достигнут конец файла
    puts("Ошибка чтения: достигнут конец файла");
else if (ferror(file)) {
    puts("Ошибка чтения файла");
```

или на C++ - наподобие

```
for(int n; file >> n; ) 
{
   // Обработка считанного значения n
}

if (file.bad())
    std::cout << "Ошибка ввода-вывода при чтении\n";
else if (file.eof())
    std::cout << "Достигнут конец файла\n";
else if (file.fail())
    std::cout << "Неверный формат данных\n";
```

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл А вы что, не понимаете, что `c>>n` **выполняет попытку считать дальше этой 1** - ну, вдруг там 123 или 11 :) - т.е. он таки **пытается читать за концом файла**. Замените `int` на `char` и убедитесь, что выводится `000`. Так что, простите, мимо кассы...

Comment: Ладно, аргументы звучат убедительно

Answer (score 6):

Также помимо флага *eof* после чтения всего файла может также выставиться флаг *fail*, и если мы захотим установить курсор на начало *fin.seekg(0, fin.beg)*, то ничего не прочитаем, т.к. флаг *fail* не сброшен. Сбросить можно с помощью *fin.clear()*. Текущее состояние можно вывести *fin.rdstate()*:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open("E://1.txt", ios_base::in);
string str;

while(getline(fin, str)) {
    cout<< str<< " " << fin.rdstate() << endl ;
}

if (fin.bad())
    std::cout << "bad" << endl;
if (fin.eof())
    std::cout << "eof" << endl;
if (fin.fail())
    std::cout << "bad | fail" << endl;

fin.clear();
fin.seekg(0, fin.beg);

if (fin.bad())
    std::cout << "bad" << endl;
if (fin.eof())
    std::cout << "eof" << endl;
if (fin.fail())
    std::cout << "bad | fail" << endl;

while(getline(fin, str)) {
    cout<<str<< " " << fin.rdstate() << endl ;
}
```