# Считывание информации из файла С++

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

пишу программу, необходимо считывать информацию из txt файла и записывать информацию в стрктуру

```
struct disp_res{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct NOTEBOOK{
    disp_res size_display;
    int regeneration_frequency;
    float diagonal;
    float size_hdd;
    float price;
    char model;
};
```

написал следующий код для этого:

```
int main() {

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    string name_file="C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\AlgoritmAndStructData\\Lab1\\Lab1\\note.txt";
    int strInFile;
    string buffer;

    nach:

    ifstream file(name_file);

    if (file.is_open()){
        strInFile = getQuantityString(file);
        NOTEBOOK* array = new NOTEBOOK[strInFile];
        int i = 0;
        file.close();

        ifstream file1(name_file);
        while(!file1.eof()){
            getline(file1, buffer);
            array[i].size_display.x=stoi(split(buffer));
            array[i].size_display.y=stoi(split(buffer));
            array[i].regeneration_frequency=stoi(split(buffer));
            array[i].diagonal=stof(split(buffer));
            array[i].size_hdd=stof(split(buffer));
            array[i].price=stof(split(buffer));
            array[i].model=strToChar(split(buffer));
            i++;
        }
        outputFile(array, strInFile);

    } else{
        if(dialog())
            goto nach;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

метод split делит строку по символу табуляции

```
string split(string str){
    string delimiter ="\t", pos_string;
    int position_delimiter = 0;

    position_delimiter = str.find(delimiter);

    if (position_delimiter==-1)
        return str;
    else{
        pos_string = str.substr(0, position_delimiter);
        str.erase(0, position_delimiter + delimiter.length());
        return pos_string;
    }
}
```

метод getQuantityString подсчитывает количество строк в файле

```
int getQuantityString(ifstream &files){
    int quantity = 0;
    string buffer ="";

    while (!files.eof()){
        getline(files, buffer);
        quantity++;
    }

    return quantity;
}
```

выдает ошибку, при попытке преобразования строки в int строка в методе main

```
array[i].size_display.x=stoi(split(buffer));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файла note.txt
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кодировка файла UTF-8. Что делаю не так, почему не работает метод `stoi()`?
По отладке посмотрел считывание происходит нормально... ну или мне так кажется[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Метод сплит отрабатывает корректно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это скорее всего не причина ваших неприятностей, но все равно ошибка: `while(!file1.eof()){` - так не делается... См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: `goto nach;` повторно инициализирует `file` приводя к неопределенному поведению. Ситуация, когда строка в `split` пустая никак не обрабатывается.

Comment: goto nach не используется сейчас в программе в принципе. когда строка пустая, это равнозначно тому, что в ней нет delimiter, т.е. вернётся пустая строка. но до этого не доходит в принципе. т.к. всё ломается при первой итерации.

Comment: по поводу while(!file1.eof()) у меня есть специальная функция, которая подсчитывает количество строк в файле, и я там использую while(!file.eof) и не возникает проблем с подсчётом строк. ранее, возможно и была такая ошибка, но у меня работает корректно этот кусок кода