# Странное поведение кода при считывании из файла

Tags: c, fprintf

Есть код, считывающий конфигурацию из текстового файла. Содержимое файла (значения, разделенные пробелами):

```
100 1690 Var1 A 1 0 0
101 1694 Var2 A 1 0 0
102 1698 Var3 A 1 0 0
1000 1000 Var4 na 1 0 0
1001 1001 Var5 na 1 0 0
5000 2807 Var6 na 1 0 0
```

Файл читаю в цикле:

```
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen(config, "r")) == NULL) {
  printf("Can not open config file %s\n", config);
  return -1;
}

int var_ioa;
int var_id;
char var_name[255];
char   mu[10];
bool sporadic;
float cyclic_interval;
char aperture[10];
var_meas_unit var_mu;
while (!feof(fp)) {

  fscanf(fp, "%d%d%s%s%d%f%s\n", &var_ioa, &var_id, var_name, mu, &sporadic, &cyclic_interval, aperture);

  printf("MU string:%s\n", mu);
 }
```

Проблема в следующем: если объявить переменную mu сразу после переменной var_name (как выше), то вывод программы следующий:

```
MU string:
MU string:
MU string:
MU string:
MU string:
MU string:
```

Если же объявление переменных сделать таким (mu последняя в списке):

```
int var_ioa;
int var_id;
char var_name[255];
bool sporadic;
float cyclic_interval;
char aperture[10];
var_meas_unit var_mu;
char   mu[10];
```

то результат корректный:

```
MU string:A
MU string:A
MU string:A
MU string:na
MU string:na
MU string:na
```

Почему такое поведение? Не могу понять.

Comment: Что-то не воспроизводится ваша ошибка... Это **весь** код? не перетираете ли вы где-то что-то в `var_name`?  Но у вас есть другая неприятность - [`while (!feof(fp))`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @Harry, дальше по коду переменная var_name копируется в другую область памяти, ее перезапись нигде не происходит.

Comment: Ну, приведите тогда минимальный пример, который можно запихнуть в компилятор и посмотреть... Текстовый файл именно такой, как показан?

Comment: @Harry, выложил полный код на [пейстбин](https://pastebin.com/eyve2PBf). Содержимое файла такое же, как выше.

Comment: @Harry, [отредактировал](https://pastebin.com/gNhFgegj)

Comment: Ну, хотите - верьте, хотите - нет - но у меня (VC++) все нормально...

Comment: @Harry, верю, потому что разобрался с проблемой. Все дело в типе bool (stdbool.h). Я собираю компилятором gcc под Linux, и при форматированном чтении fprintf происходит несоответствие спецификатора %d и типа bool. Объявил как int, все работает. Спасибо за участие )