# fscanf игнорирует символ '\n'

Tags: c, файлы

Хочу решить следующую задачу: дан текстовый файл, считать из него информацию и перезаписать ее в новый файл изменив слово `"one"` на `1` и слово `"nine"` на `9`.
**Пример :**
file1.txt
one * nine = nine
nine / one = nine

file2.txt - результативный файл
1 * 9 = 9
9 / 1 = 9

Написал такое решение:

```
FILE *wfile = fopen("Temp.txt", "w"); // откроем старый файл

// запишем в него две строки
fprintf(wfile, "%s", "one * nine = nine");
fprintf(wfile, "%s", "\nnine / one = nine");

fclose(wfile); // закроем его

wfile = fopen("Result.txt", "w"); // открываем новый файл для записи
FILE *rfile = fopen("Temp.txt", "r"); // открываем старый для чтения

char tmp[100];
while (!feof(rfile)) { 
    fscanf(rfile, "%s ", &tmp); // считываем слово из старого файла

    if (!strcmp(tmp, "one")) // если это "one",
        fprintf(wfile, "%d ", 1); // то запишем в новый файл 1
    // аналогично для "nine"
    else if (!strcmp(tmp, "nine")) 
        fprintf(wfile, "%d ", 9);
    else // или же это обычное слово
        fprintf(wfile, "%s ", tmp);
}

fclose(rfile);
fclose(wfile);
```

Программа работает **почти** правильно. Но есть одна проблема.
Если в старом файле я имею такие две строки:
one * nine = nine
nine / one = nine
То в результативном получу одну:
1 * 9 = 9 9 / 1 = 9

Почему так выходит и как это исправить?
Спасибо.

Comment: ну так добавьте перевод строки руками

Comment: И опять это вечное `while (!feof(rfile))`...

Comment: @pavel, после каждого слова добавлять перенос нет смысла, т.к. это не правильно. А вот как Вы предлагаете сделать перевос именно строки?

Comment: @Harry, а как правильно тогда? :)

Comment: @BorisMakhlin правильно - проверять возвращаемое значение функции scanf. А вообще советую fgets использовать. Она читает ровно строку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0

Comment: Форматированный ввод `fscanf` **всегда** игнорирует пробельные символы (кроме форматов `%c` и `%[]`) . Как всегда было и как и должно быть. Почему для вас это явилось сюрпризом?