# Посимвольное считывание из файла

Tags: c, файлы

Файл содержит n-ое количество строк, нужно считать эти строки в массив (одномерный, в одну строку).  fgets() считывает только первую строку с файла. Попытался сделать вот так:

```
    int mas(char *filename, char *arr){
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rt");
if(f == NULL){
return 1;
}
    //fgets(arr, 1000, f);
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    while(!feof(f)){
        arr[i] = fgetc(f);
        if(arr[i] == '\n'){
            arr[i] = ' ';
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Но после передачи файла в программу, в терминале выводятся три непонятных символа + Segmentation Fault 11. Причем вывод получившегося массива не запрашивался

Comment: *fgets() считывает только первую строку с файла.* - что за ерунда?! Просто работайте с ней в цикле! И еще - гляньте [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0). И, кстати, **что** вы передаете в функцию в качестве аргумента `arr`? Как вы ее вызываете?

Comment: *Но после передачи файла в программу* - а где, собственно говоря, программа?! Я не вижу функции *main()*.  Я не вижу, где и как вызывается функция *mas()*. Вы вообще - о чём пишете?!

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать системный вызов read, если вы работаете в posix-системе.

```
/*пример функции, которая читает все в одну строку */
void superread(int fd, char *str)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (0 != read(fd, &str[i], 1))
        i++;
}
```

После этих манипуляций вы прочитаете файл в одну строку. В Windows нужно либо использовать Cygwin, либо же использовать fread.