# Ошибка в программе. Ввод массива из файла. Язык C

Tags: c, массивы, файлы

ошибка: метка может быть частью оператора, а декларация не является оператором

```
FILE *f = fopen("my.txt", "r");
```

Эта часть кода находится в цикле switch в case 3. Жалуется на FILE

```
case 3:
        FILE *f = fopen("my.txt", "r");
        while(!feof(f)) {
            int i = 0;
            fscanf(f, "%d", A[i]);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(f);
        break;
```

Comment: Декларация не является оператором, как вам ясно сказал компилятор. Поставьте `;` после `case 3:` и эта ошибка исчезнет. Хотя других ошибок тут хватает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
case 3:
  {
    FILE *f = fopen("my.txt", "r");
    while(!feof(f)) {
        int i = 0;
        fscanf(f, "%d", A[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(f);
  }
  break;
```

И еще - стандартная ошибка `while(!feof(f))`... См. [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0).

А еще - совершенно бессмысленное

```
int i = 0;
fscanf(f, "%d", A[i]);
i++;
```

в цикле, так как на каждой итерации `i` обнуляется, и вы читаете все, что есть - в одну переменную. Опять же, не думаю, что `A[i]` - *указатель, куда читать*, скорее всего вы имели в виду

```
fscanf(f, "%d", &A[i]);
```

Да и проверять надо - открылся ли файл благополучно, кстати...

Интересно, все ошибки нашел? :)