# Считать файл с кириллицей

Tags: c++, кодировка

Вот код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ifstream f("1.txt");
    string buff = "";
    while (!f.eof()) {
        f >> buff;
        cout << buff << endl;
    }
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

В 1.txt написано: "Привет мир!". Проблема в том что в консоли отображаются каракули. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в какой кодировке сам файл? Не utf8, случаем? И, кстати, `while (!f.eof()) {` - это [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)...

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");`. Посмотрите, что получится.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй заменить `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian")` на

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

и в загловках добавить `#include <Windows.h>`

п.с если что не правильно, не судите, только начал учить C++

---

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    ifstream f("1.txt");
    string buff = "";
    while (!f.eof()) {
        f >> buff;
        cout << buff << endl;
    }
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```