# Чтение первых двух слов строки файла

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.Мне необходимо записать слова в два массива. Один массив записывает только первое слово, а второй второе.Но не в этом проблема,что если строка состоит из более кол-во слов?! Как мне выполнить переход на следующую строку после записи этих двух слов?

```
char logfile[256];
char logpass[256];
while(!fout.eof())
          {
           fout>>logfile;
           fout>>logpass;
          };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проигнорировать все до конца строки:

```
fout.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Хуже, если в строке одно слово - второе тогда у вас будет считано из второй строки :)

Только учтите еще, что

```
while(!fout.eof())
```

[это ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Answer (score 2):

Считать сразу всю строку, а из нее - уже слова:

```
string s;
if (getline(fout,s)) {
    istringstream ss(s);
    ss>>logfile;
    ss>>logpass;
    }
```

Comment: а зачем считать  ненужную часть, если можно считать сколько угодно?

Comment: А какая разница? при игнорировании точно так же будет читаться вся строка, только в никуда. А если ТС захочется еще что-то делать с остатком строки, то вот ему способ, который позволяет делать со строкой что угодно.

Comment: не согласен, при игнорировании работа ведется на уровне буффера(самая быстрая операция), и  инициализировать символьную строку этими же символами, а потом еще и  пользоваться услугами обьекта   istringstream , слышком для такого простого желания