# Чтение из файла в массивы

Tags: c++

Есть файл с таким набором точек:

7496,9214700000002       0,20898565871874042
   7460,2758599999997       0,20913999999999999
   2702,1319699999999       0,22917999999999999
   2441,7552300000002       0,24504999999999999
   2356,8917000000001       0,24748999999999999
   2310,6025000000000       0,26036999999999999
   2167,8774699999999       0,27059000000000000
   2027,0811600000000       0,29768000000000000

Мне нужно считать 1 число из строки в массив mX ,а второе в mY.Не понимаю как это сделать,да так чтобы он еще и на следующую строчку переходил.
Пытался так,но не получается

```
ifstream infile("txt.txt");
while(!infile.eof()){
  infile>>mX>>mY
```

Comment: Что такое "не получается"? (И в программах на С и С++ не должно быть прямых обращений к `eof()`. Откуда вы взяли такую манеру написания цикла?)

Comment: @AnT ну почему-то 1 число считывается ,а 2 нет.Думал,что это хорошая проверка на конец файла

Comment: У вас настройки локали вообще какие? Как числа писаться должны: через запятую или через точку? Почему у вас в файле именно запятые?

Comment: @AnT Большое спасибо,я и не заметил запятые ,что привело к ошибке.Не подскажите ,почему  после конца файла считывается еще раз и записываются как 0 в оба массива?

Comment: Вот именно потому, что устроили цикл с предусловием `eof`. Это практически всегда ошибка.

Comment: @AnT А на что его правильно будет заменить?

Comment: Первый вопрос следует закрывать, как вызванный опечаткой, второй - как дубль для https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0  У кого там золото по С++ есть - закройте, а то я спросонок не туда попал, не тот дубль указал, пришлось переоткрывать, и теперь закрыть не могу...

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%fl %fl", &mX[i], &mY[i])
```

Реализуй считывание из файла с помощью `scanf` и по идее он сам будет переходить на новую строчку. Если данные будут записаны корректно: через пробел и по два числа - все заработает.

Comment: Вопрос с меткой C++, Ваше предложение C-style

Comment: функция scanf прекрасно работает и используется в c++, так что замечание странное

Comment: то что она работает, это знают все. Но используя C++ надо использовать функционал С++. Для С есть extern “C”

Comment: scanf является частью функционала c++, никто не запрещает его использовать, меня за это еще ни разу не арестовали

Comment: Нет, он является частью библиотеки языка Си и не является частью функционала языка C++. Просто с++ поддерживает функционал Си

Comment: Хорошо, скажу по-другому. Если c++ поддерживает функционал c, почему нельзя это использовать?
Если c++ поддерживает эту библотеку, она априори становится частью функционала.

Comment: А зачем ? Есть более гибкие инструменты c++, а если вы используете функционал си, он должен быть обернуть в extern