# Цикл чтения из ifstream не дочитывает файл до конца

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream, binary-file

Имеется бинарный файл размером 104,688,605 байт.

Читаю его в цикле:

```
ifstream fs("1.cnv",ios::binary); 
int counter = 0;
char c;
while (fs>>c){
   counter++;
}

cout<<counter<<endl;
```

В итоге получаю 101,914,339 байт. 
Где еще 3 тысячи?

Следующие вариации цикла дают точно такой же результат:

```
while (!fs.eof()) {
        fs>>c;



while (fs.good) {
        fs>>c;
```

Comment: Для чтения бинарного файла необходимо использовать `read`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы читались **все** символы, нужно указать, что пробельные символы тоже нужно читать:

```
int counter = 0;
char c;
fs >> noskipws;
while (fs>>c){
    counter++;
}
```

Обратите внимание на `fs >> noskipws;`.

Вариант

```
while (!fs.eof()) {
```

будет работать неверно, потому что `eof()` сработает только *после* неудавшегося чтения за концом файла (см. этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)), а

```
while (fs.good) {
```

тем более - потому что `fs.good` - это не вызов функции :)

P.S. Но если вдруг вам нужен просто размер файла - то для этого есть свои способы, не требующие чтения...

Comment: Я думаю, что `while (fs.good)` просто опечатка, ит что автор хотел написать `while (fs.good())`.