# Поиск числа в строке c++

Tags: c++

В файле содержится строка "Число 10 число 20". Первое число обрабатывается, а на второе выдает стабильно 0. При этом, если выводить только индексы первых элементов чисел в строке (6 и 16)  - все работает. В чем может быть проблема?
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    string line;

    ifstream in("F:\\foo.txt"); 

    if (in.is_open())
    {
        getline(in, line);
    }

    int digits = line.find_first_of("1234567890");
    int digits2 = line.find_last_of("1234567890");

    int number = atoi(line.c_str() + digits);
    int number2 = atoi(line.c_str() + digits2);


    cout << number << endl;
    cout << number2 << endl;
    in.close();     

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Итак,

```
int digits2 = line.find_last_of("1234567890");
```

Что же мы видим в `"Число 10 число 20"`? Точно! Самую распоследнюю цифру - 0 из 20.

```
int number2 = atoi(line.c_str() + digits2);
```

Что же тут такое `line.c_str() + digits2`? Это строка `"0"`

Что `atoi` должен вернуть для такой строки, как не 0?

И чему вы удивлены? И - с индексами:

```
 Число 10 число 20
           1111111
 01234567890123456
```

Все верно, 6 - индекс, с которого начинается *10 число 20*, 16 - индекс последнего нуля...

Answer (score 3):

> При этом, если выводить только индексы первых элементов чисел в строке (6 и 16) - все работает

Вы совершенно правильно заметили, что второй индекс равен 16. А теперь посмотрите, на какой символ он указывает

```
Число 10 число 20
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          1111111
01234567890123456
```

Т.е. `digits2` указывает на **последнюю** цифру в строке. Что как бы логично. Строка

```
int digits2 = line.find_last_of("1234567890");
```

находит последнее вхождение цифры.

Чтобы программа работала, вам нужно сместиться влево от `digits2` на начало числа

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм решения: (предлагаю Вам переписать Ваш вариант)

1) Разбить строки на лексемы через stringstream

2) проверить цифры или нет

3) обработать (сделать то, что Вам нужно)

Вместо файла будет просто строка(представим что Вы туда сдампили файл) Вот Вам 2 схожих метода как это сделать

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>


void foo(std::string str) {

    std::cout << "first" << std::endl;

    std::stringstream ss{ str };
    std::string tmp{};
    std::vector<int64_t> data_v;

    while (ss >> tmp) {
        if (std::all_of(std::begin(tmp), std::end(tmp), std::isdigit)) {
            data_v.push_back(std::stoi(tmp));
        }
    }

    for (const auto& v : data_v) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}


void foo2(std::string str) {

    std::cout << "second" << std::endl;


    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss), end;
    std::vector<std::string> vec_str(begin, end);

    std::vector<int> data_v;

    auto f{ [&](const std::string& s) { if (std::count_if(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::isdigit) == s.size()) { data_v.push_back(std::atoi(s.c_str())); }} };
    std::for_each(std::begin(vec_str), std::end(vec_str), f);

    for (const auto& v : data_v) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
}


int main() {

    std::string str{ "num 10 num 20" };

    foo(str);

    foo2(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А теперь добавьте в строку еще один пробел - `"num 10 num 20 "` - и расскажите, почему ваш первый метод перестал правильно работать... :)

Comment: @Harry а теперь просто перед пробросом строки в функцию передать ее в какой нибудь trim и расскажите, почему ваше правильное сообщение перестало быть актуальным :))

Comment: Т.е. вас даже не интересует, где у вас ошибка? В детстве велосипед тоже вместо чтоб чинить - веревочками подвязывали? Мое сообщение не перестало быть актуальным и не перестанет, пока будут писать вот эту хрень: `while (!ss.eof()) {`. [Учите матчасть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)!

Comment: @Harry  давайте заменим на while (ss >> tmp ) надеюсь теперь вы будете довольны )

Comment: Конечно. Именно этого я и добивался своими намеками...

Comment: @Harry спасибо ) просто писал не думая, собирая код из того что было под рукой :)  да ошибка глупая)