# Передача аргументов через консоль Windows

Tags: c++, windows, строки, файлы

Необходимо задать через консоль windows данные:

1. Название проекта.
2. Путь к файлу.
3. шифрование/дешифрирование.
4. Ключ.

*Я код написал но не понимаю почему он не работает, я захожу в директорию с проектом, debug и внутри него у меня есть 1.txt в который нужно переписать слово на зашифрованное, я запускаю через командную строку через cmd, он пишет якобы я указал неправильный путь к файлу*

```
int main(int argC, char** argV) {
/*
Используется шифр цезаря, я уверен код рабочий но не понимаю в какой последовательности запускать консоль,
знаю что нужно запускать через директорию с проектом в папке debug, при помощи cmd но он не работает должным образом
*/
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
if (argC==4) {
    cout << argV[0] << endl; //Имя проекта
    cout << argV[1] << endl; //Путь к файлу,в директорий debug/1.txt
    cout << argV[2] << endl; //shifr,deshifr
    cout << argV[3] << endl; //Ключ

    int key = atoi(argV[3]); //Из строки ключа делаем число
    char str[250]; // Создаём строку для записи

    ifstream readFile; //Открываем для ввода(чтения)
    readFile.open(argV[1]); 
    ofstream writeFile; //Открываем для вывода(записи)
    writeFile.open(argV[1]);

    if (readFile) {
        cout << "Читаем текст...";
        if (argV[2] == "shifr") {
            while (!readFile.eof()) {
                readFile.getline(str, 250);
            }
        }
        else if (argV[2] == "deshifr") {
            while (!readFile.eof()) {
                readFile.getline(str, 250);
            }
        }
        if (writeFile && argV[2] == "shifr") {
            cout << "Записываем зашифровоные слова...";
            for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
                if (str[i]==' ') {
                    writeFile << ' ';
                }
                if (str[i]=='\n') {
                    writeFile << '\n';
                }
                if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
                    str[i] != (key % 26);
                    if (str[i] > 'Z') {
                        str[i] -= 26;
                    }
                }
                if (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') {
                    str[i] != (key % 26);
                    if (str[i]>'z') {
                        str[i] -= 26;
                    }
                }
                writeFile << str << "\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Вы указали неверный путь к файлу.";
        }
        if (writeFile && argV[2] == "deshifr") {
            cout << "Дешифруем ваш текст.";
            for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
                if (str[i] == ' ') {
                    writeFile << ' ';
                }
                if (str[i] == '\n') {
                    writeFile << '\n';
                }
                if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
                    str[i] != (key % 26);
                    if (str[i] > 'Z') {
                        str[i] += 26;
                    }
                }
                if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
                    str[i] != (key % 26);
                    if (str[i] > 'z') {
                        str[i] += 26;
                    }
                }
                writeFile << str << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    readFile.close();
    writeFile.close();
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Вот такое сравнение строк

```
argV[2] == "shifr"
```

не работает, потому что фактически сравниваются значения указателей. Для сравнения содержимого строк в стиле C (массивов `char`) используйте функцию типа `strcmp`.

А именно к этому сравнению в вашей программе привязано ваше сообщение о неверном имени файла..

И еще - вот такой способ чтения

```
while (!readFile.eof()) {
```

без проверки результата чтения внутри цикла неверен - см. [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342).

Comment: В дополнение к ответу Harry... На сколько помню, **argv[0]** содержит имя запускаемого файла, Ваши параметры начинаются с  **argv[1]**. Соответственно, **argC** у Вас должно быть равно 5.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Да вроде как раз тут у него все верно, он просто `argv[0]` называет имя проекта, но в командную строку не вводит.

Comment: Harry, может быть. Просто я на основе текста сделал предположение, что у него 4 пользовательских параметра. Вполне допускаю, что я ошибся :)

Comment: Странно, проблема с ошибкой в указаний пути никуда не делись но к ним прибавилось то что он стирает всё что уже есть в 1.txt но не перезаписывает,я так и не смог понять где ошибся.И по поводу чтение я так и не понял