# При компиляции выскакивает ошибка APPCRASH

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Написал программу в Codeblocks на C++. Программа считывает текст с файла и заново его вводит.

```
char text;
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("2.txt");
if(inFile.fail()){
    cerr << "Error! " << endl;
    exit(1);
}
vector <string> v;
for(int i = 0; !inFile.eof(); i++){
    inFile.get(text);
    v[i] = text;
}
inFile.close();
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("2.txt");
for(int f = 0; f < v.size(); f++){

    outFile << v[f];
}
outFile.close();
return 0;
```

[image]

При компиляции выходит эта ошибка.
Перезапускал комп, codeblocks, и его настройки компилятора. Устанавливал net framework.
Ничего не помогает

Comment: Не при компиляции, а при выполнении. `v[i] = text;` записывает мимо границ вектора, вместо этого нужно использовать `.push_back()`.

Comment: И ещё загляните [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: HolyBlackCat, Спасибо, братан. Очень сильно помог. 

Comment: EOF, Спасибо за полезную ссылку.