# не работает getline c++

Tags: c++

VS 2019 пишет, что отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженной функции. Getline подчёркнут красным

```
  #include<fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        int kol=0;
        ofstream fout;
        ifstream read;
        string file="file.txt";
        read.open(file);
        if (!read.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Файл не открылся!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            char a;
            cout << "Файл открыт!\n";
            while (read.get(a))
            {
                kol++;
            }

            char* A = new char[kol];
            char p;
            int* B = new int[kol-1];
            char b;
            int po = 0;
            while (!read.eof())
            {
                getline(read, b);
                po++;
            }


        for (int j = 0;j < kol;j++)
        {
            cout << A[j];   
        }
    }
    read.close(); 
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Не к вопросу - но сколько можно это `while (!read.eof())`?... Потом у вас и этот вопрос встанет... Превентивно - читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Comment: Зачем тебе getline к одному char-у?

Answer (score 0):

Вторым аргументов getline вы подаёте символьную переменную `b`. В неё нельзя считать строку.

Объявите

```
string b;
```

вместо

```
char b;
```