# Ошибка Exception thrown at 0x008C22A2 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000F0000

Tags: c++

Помогите разобратся с проблемай, записываю данные в файл через ifstream читаю содержимое также.
Если файл пустой по программа работает, следует записать что то в файл при повторном запуске не запускается в VisualStudio показывает ошибку

Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0x6C438C.

```
#include
#include
#include
#include

using namespace std;

class Tovar {
public:
string nazvanie = "";
string proizvoditelj = "";
string sotrudnik = "";
double cena = 0;
int id = 0;
short int kolicestvo = 0;
Tovar() {
string nazvanie = "";
string proizvoditelj = "";
string sotrudnik = "";
double cena = 0;
int id = 0;
short int kolicestvo = 0;
}

Tovar(int i, string n, string p, string sot, double c, short int k)
{
id = i;
nazvanie = n;
proizvoditelj = p;
sotrudnik = sot;
cena = c;
kolicestvo = k;
}
bool operator == (const Tovar& s) const { return id == s.id; }
bool operator != (const Tovar& s) const { return! operator==(s); }
};
list tovarlist;

int max_id()
{
if (::tovarlist.size() < 1) {
return 0;
};
::tovarlist.sort([](const Tovar& f, const Tovar& s) { return f.id > s.id; });
return ::tovarlist.front().id;
}

int read()
{
ifstream file_obj;

file_obj.open("tovar.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

Tovar obj; //

file_obj.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
if (!file_obj.is_open())
{
cout << "Files is not open!" << endl;
}
else
{
while (!file_obj.eof()) {
::tovarlist.push_back(obj);
file_obj.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
}
}
file_obj.close();
return 0;
}

int save()
{
ofstream file_obj;
Tovar obj;

file_obj.open("tovar.bin", ios::in | ios::trunc);
for (Tovar t : ::tovarlist) {
obj.id = t.id;
obj.nazvanie = t.nazvanie;
obj.cena = t.cena;
obj.proizvoditelj = t.proizvoditelj;
obj.kolicestvo = t.kolicestvo;
obj.sotrudnik = t.sotrudnik;
file_obj.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));}

file_obj.close();
return 0;
cout << "Saved";
}

void add()
{
string nazvanie, proizvoditelj, sotrudnik,sotrudnik_name, sotrudnik_surname, temp_sotrudnik;
double cena;
short int kolicestvo, temp;
string temp_string;
cin >> nazvanie;
cin >> proizvoditelj;
cin >> cena;
cin >> kolicestvo;
cin >> sotrudnik_name;
cin >> sotrudnik_surname;
temp_sotrudnik = sotrudnik_name + " " + sotrudnik_surname;
Tovar tovar = Tovar(max_id() + 1, nazvanie, proizvoditelj, temp_sotrudnik, cena, kolicestvo);
::tovarlist.push_back(tovar);
save();
}
}



void print() {
    header();
    for (Tovar t : ::tovarlist) // cikl prolistivaet vesj falj i vivodit objekti iz lista
    {
        cout.width(4); cout << internal << t.id << " |" << " ";
        cout.width(12); cout << internal << t.nazvanie << " |" << " ";
        cout.width(7); cout << internal << t.cena << " |" << " ";
        cout.width(21); cout << internal << t.proizvoditelj << " |" << " ";
        cout.width(11); cout << internal << t.kolicestvo << " |" << " ";
        cout.width(25); cout << internal << t.sotrudnik << " |" << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Первое, что бросается в глаза, что не так с вашими include? Второе, здесь нет выполнения кода на c++ прямо на сайте.

Comment: А еще - кроме ошибки сохранения - у вас эта ошибка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Answer (score 0):

В коде желательно было указать main() функцию. По обьявлению классов и функций сложно что то сказать. Касательно самой ошибки - исключение вызывается к не инициализированной переменной.

Comment: В main просто 
mani { read();add();print() }

Comment: Неинициализированная `0x000F0000`? Как-то маловероятно.