# Запуск программы через командную строку!(Windows,С++)

Tags: c++, файлы, консоль

Добрый день уважаемые пользователи,столкнулся с одной проблемой.В общем нужно,запустив программу через командную строку получить на выход .csv файл.(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV)

> Если что,расширение конечного файла не важно,если не слышали про
>   .csv,просто представьте что это .txt

**Проблема:** *никакого файла после выполнения программы не создается вообще!*

**Аргументы командной  строки:**

> Project1.exe input.txt result.csv

**Код:**

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    //Вывожу аргументы,чтобы убедиться в правильности их использования.
    std::cout << argv[1] << " " << argv[2] << std::endl;

    std::ifstream input;
    input.open(argv[1]);//argv[1]=input.txt.
    std::ofstream output;
    output.open(argv[2]);//argv[2]=result.csv.

    if (input.is_open())
    {
        std::string str;
        while (!input.eof())
        {
            str = " ";
            std::getline(input, str);
            output << str<<"\n";
        }
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();

    //Чтобы убедиться,сработает ли программа вообще.
    std::cout << "It worked!!!\n";

    //Для задержки консоли.
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Информация из консоли после завершения работы:**

**P.S:** "MMM"-для конфиденциальности

> C:\Users\MMM>C:\MMM\MMM\MMM\MMM\MMM\MMM\Project1.exe input.txt
>   result.csv
>
> input.txt result.csv
>
> It worked!!!

**Скрин:**

[image]

**Скрин текстового документа:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "input.open("argv[1]");" - Чего?! Подумайте еще раз

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch поправил,все-равно не создается файл:(

Comment: я у себя запустил - нормально работает. Копирует текст из инпута в резалт. Правда, я захардкодил имена входного и выходного файла. Так что, видимо, ошибка в обработке аргументов.

Comment: @S.H. я тестил этот код не через консоль,все работает.А если запустить через консоль все также-глухо(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шутить изволите?

```
output.open("argv[2]");
```

Вы просите создать файл с именем `"argv[2]"`. Не с тем, что передано в командной строке, а с именем, которое есть строка "argv[2]"...

Уберите кавычки -

```
ofstream  output(argv[2]);
```

Вы же не пишете

```
std::string "str";
```

Кстати, вот так делать:

```
while (!input.eof())
```

[неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)!

Comment: Поправил,но все-равно не создается никакого файла(

Comment: **while (!input.eof())** Почему неправильно?

Comment: Я дал ссылку на ответ, почему - щелкните на слове "неправильно"..