# Не выводит информацию из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, io

Доброе утро. Задача: написать прогу, которая считывает текст из файла и выводит на экран только строки, не содержащие двузначных чисел.
Написать то написал, все работает, но не выводит строки :(
Можете помочь с выводом?

```
   #include "vector"
   #include "fstream"
   #include "iostream"
   #include "string"


   using namespace std;
   string chislo;
   string cifra;
   int j;

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {

       vector<string> str1;
       setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
       cout << "Введите свое название файла типа name.xxx: ";
       string fileName;
       cin >> fileName;
       ifstream in(fileName.c_str());
       if (!in.is_open())
       {
           cout << "Такой файл не найден в корневой папке программы!" << endl;
           system("pause");
           return 0;
       }
       cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;
       cout << endl;
       string str;
       string temp;
       cout << "Исходный  текст" << endl;
       cout << "=================" << endl;
       while (!in.eof()) {
           str = "";
           getline(in, str);
           cout << str << endl;

       }
       in.clear();
       in.seekg(0);
       cout << "Отредактированный  текст" << endl;
       cout << "=================" << endl;
       //Считываем числа в массив
       while (!in.eof())
       {

           in >> cifra;
           str1.push_back(chislo);

       }

       //Проверяем текст на числа
       for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
       {

           for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
               if (isdigit(str[i]))
               {
                   for (int j = i + 1; str[j] != '\0' && isdigit(str[j]); ++j);
                   if (j - i == 2)
                   {
                       cout << str << endl;
                   }
                   i = j;
               }
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Наступит ли когда-то знаменательный день, когда наконец хотя бы неделю никто не напишет это ужасное [`while (!in.eof())`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)?... По делу - дайте точное определения, что вы ищете. Это должно быть отдельное слово из двух цифр? или просто 2 цифры подряд? `aa12dd`, `aa 12, dd`, `135+12=147`? Как *формально* определяется наличие двузначного числа? От этого же зависит и решение...

Comment: Просто файл, в котором такой текст: 
"123
4
123
43
1
134"
Например. Все они в столбик. И нужно, чтобы программа вывела строки с однозначными

Comment: Т.е. каждая строка ("*Все они в столбик*") содержит одно число? И что, теперь условие поменялось - "* нужно, чтобы программа вывела строки с однозначными*" - ранее вы говорили не выводить с двузначными. Поймите, это не цепляние к словам, это суровая реальность - пока нет абсолютно точно сформулированного ТЗ, результат будет один: ХЗ...

Answer (score 0):

```c
int isdigit(char chr);

// includes

#define NUM_LEN 2U

int main() {
    char** strs;
    unsigned long strCount;

    // init `strs`

    unsigned long seqDigitCnt = 0;

    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < strCount; ++i) {
        for (char* chrPtr = strs[i]; *chrPtr; ++chrPtr) {
            if (isdigit(*chrPtr))
                ++seqDigitCnt;
            else if (seqDigitCnt == NUM_LEN) {
                seqDigitCnt = 0;

                std::cout << str << std::endl;

                break;
            }
            else
                seqDigitCnt = 0;
        }

        seqDigitCnt = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что, еще есть компиляторы, которые `register` понимают? :)

Comment: тсс... ни слова больше!) (я забыл :) )

Comment: Спасибо)
Как это можно в код интегрировать? По ходу внедрения у меня Вижл ругается.

Comment: @AlexNel ругается по поводу чего

Comment: Не распознает < init `strs`>
И не определяет ++seqDigitCnt;

Comment: @AlexNel так оно и не должно, это вы должны дописать ваш способ считывания строк))) (я исправил на комментарий что вы видели). я так делаю как раз таки чтобы компилятор и ругал, ведь вы должны заменить этот код на ваш. теперь у вас всё будет работать (если замените код, конечно же)

Comment: @AlexNel я также исправил код из моего ответа (сделайте его "ре-копинг")