# Проблема с оператором ">>" std::ifstream

Tags: c++

```
    void skipLine(std::ifstream* ifs)
    {
        char t;
        do 
        {
            *ifs >> t;
        } while (t == '\n');
    }

    unsigned int lastId()
    {
        std::ifstream ifs;
        ifs.open(filename);
        int id = 1;
        while (!ifs.eof())
        {
            ifs >> id;
            skipLine(&ifs);
        }
        ifs.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

(да, сам алгоритм, скорее всего кривой, но позже исправится, интересно, почему не компилируется)
ошибка компиляции с отсылкой к `*ifs >> t`:
"*бинарный ">>": "std::ifstream" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору*"
В чём загвоздка?

Comment: [не воспроизводится](https://godbolt.org/z/DEWi6z)

Comment: хм, запустил отдельно, как функции, а не как методы класса, действительно, работают исправно, весь класс я уж не смогу залить, так что надежда только на опыт или понимание речи компилятора

Comment: Вы случайно `#include <fstream>` не пропустили? :) И еще - в коде как минимум две глупости: `do ... while (t == '\n');` будет читать символы, пока они конец строки, а не до первого символа `\n`. Вторая - см. тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Вы случайно #include  не пропустили? :)

Мда, крч такая ошибка возникает, когда не подключен fstream  )