# Непонятная ошибка C

Tags: c

При отладке, код в самом конце выдаёт такую ошибку(скрин). Пытался гуглить, вроде похоже на утечку памяти, но как исправить не пойму. Спасибо.
[image: Ошибка]

```
struct person {
    char lastName[15];
    char firstName[15];
    char age[2];
};

int main()
{
    FILE* filePtr;

    filePtr = fopen("nameage.txt", "wb");

    if (filePtr == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "File couldn't open.");
    else
    {
        struct person blankPerson = { "unassigned", "", "0" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            fwrite(&blankPerson, sizeof(struct person), 1, filePtr);

        struct person person;

        puts("Enter LastName, FirstName, Age.");
        puts("Enter EOF to stop.");
        
        printf("?\t");
        scanf("%s%s%s", &person.lastName, &person.firstName, person.age);

        int start = 1;
        while (!feof(stdin))
        {
            fwrite(&person, sizeof(struct person), 1, filePtr);
            printf("?\t");
            scanf("%s%s%s", &person.lastName, &person.firstName, person.age);
        }
        rewind(filePtr);

        fclose(filePtr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `struct person` писать просто `person`, например: `person blankPerson = { "unassigned", "", "0" };`

Comment: Во-первых, вот это `struct person person;` вызывает подозрение. Лучше назовите структуру и объект по-разному, хотя бы для читаемости кода. Во-вторых, вопрос: компилируете как код С или С++?

Comment: 1. Вводите что-то, превышающее по размеру строку, в которую вводите. 2. Неверно обрабатываете конец файла - так `while (!feof(stdin))` делать нельзя - см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Comment: Так это цэ или цэ++? Большая часть кода как будто бы на цэ, но часть на цэ++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тексте программы - классические ошибки.

```
scanf("%s%s%s", &person.lastName, &person.firstName, person.age);
```

%s требует указателя, а ему подсовывают адрес указателя. Самое интересное, что age вводится правильно. Удалите эти амперсанды.

Также вызывает большой вопрос объявление age как char[2]. Таким образом можно будет ввести возраст только от 0 до 9 - завершающий ноль то нужен.

struct person person;  - это нормальная сишная штука.

Comment: адрес-то у массивов берется.

Comment: массив умеет "деградировать" (или притворятся) в указатель.

Comment: вы меня не так поняли. Условно, `&arr == (type*)arr`.

Comment: Спасибо. Что-то я не обратил внимания, что я в массивы считываю... А нормально, что мне приходится 3 EOF вводить, чтобы остановиться?

Comment: нет конечно. Вы используете feof неверно. Просто проверяйте результат scanf - он возвращает кол-во введенных элементов. Если там ноль - значит ничего не ввели. Ну и так далее.

Comment: мне интересны минусаторы, которые ходят, минусуют и молчат.

Comment: @KoVadim я не минусовал, если что )

Comment: та тут какой то минусатор-мазохист. ходит и пачками минусует.

Comment: @ГеннадийСамойлов 3 EOF - это вы 3 раза Ctrl-Z жмете?...