# Во время исполнения программа вылетает

Tags: c++, файлы, ввод

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main () {
unsigned long long int A[1000000000], S, s;
ifstream infile ("input.txt");
ofstream outfile ("output.txt");
int N, x;

while ( !infile.eof() ) {
    infile >> N;
    for( int i=0; i<N; ++i ){
        infile >> A[i];
        S = S + A[i];
    }
    s = sqrt(S);
    outfile << s;
    S = 0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Переполнение размера стека  для `unsigned long long int A[1000000000]`. В линукс размер 8Мбайт. В винде 1Мбайт.

Comment: теперь ничего не выводит в файл

Comment: Не испольуйте никакие массивы. Считайте по одному числу.

Comment: Переменные S и s никак не инициализированы

Comment: а как тогда без массива, если заранее не известно количество чисел

Comment: Ну... Просто заведите еще одну переменную, и вместо `A[i]` напишите название переменной.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, кстати, с этим вопросом - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
int main ()
{
    ifstream infile ("input.txt");
    ofstream outfile ("output.txt");

    for(unsigned long long N, S; infile >> N; )
    {
        S = 0;
        for(unsigned long long i = 0, x; i < N; ++i )
        {
            infile >> x;
            S += x;
        }
        outfile << sqrt(S) << endl;
    }
}
```

Типы данных сохранил ваши, хотя и не уверен в их необходимости.