# Вывод текста из файла в его исходном виде

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, fstream, работа-с-текстом

Есть файл, с помощью библиотеки fstream могу открыть его и и вывести все числа и буквы. Однако проблема в том, что файл не выводится в своем исходном виде. То есть если на одной строке есть пробел, то два слова в консоли будут выводится с разных строк. Как можно изменить данный код, что бы шёл вывод строк как в файле.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <String>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void fl(int f=0, int v=0) {
  string a;
  string b;
  ifstream file;
  file.open(" ");//путь к файлу надо указать
  getline(cin, a);
  while (!file.eof()) {
    file >> a;;
    cout << a << endl;
 }

  file.close();
 }
int main()
{
   string a;
   fl();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void fl(const char * filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename);
    string s;
    while(getline(file, s))
        cout << s << endl;
}

int main()
{
    fl("myfile");
}
```

И учтите - за вот это:

```
while (!file.eof())
```

[маленьким программистам копчик массируют](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)...