# C++ fstream : Не могу записать в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

У меня есть файл myFile.txt, который содержит числа вроде 1 2 3 4 6. Мне нужно поменять местами максимальное и минимальное значения с помощью fstream. Это моя функция.

```
void File26() {
stack<int> numbers;
fstream fs;
fs.open("myFile.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);

if (!fs.is_open()) {
    cout << "can't open file myFile.txt" << endl;
} else {
    int min;
    int max;
    int i_min = 0;
    int i_max = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (!fs.eof()) {
        string s;
        fs >> s;
        int x = stoi(s);
        numbers.push(x);
        if (i == 0) {
            min = x;
            max = x;
        } else {
            if (x < min) {
                swap(x, min);
                i_min = i;
            }
            if (x > max) {
                swap(x, max);
                i_max = i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = numbers.size();
    while (!numbers.empty()) {
        int x = numbers.top();
        i--;
        numbers.pop();
        if (i == i_min) {
            x = max;
        }
        if (i == i_max) {
            x = min;
        }
        cout << x << ", " << endl;
        fs << x << " ";
    }
}
fs.close();
```

}

Comment: In Console it works, but when I try to write something in the file it doesn't work

Comment: Да что ж за напасть - `while (!fs.eof())`... В каком-то учебнике кто-то такую ерунду написал, что ли?... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. вы уже дошли до конца файла, то под конец произошла ошибка чтения, а так же указатель в файле стоит в конце файла.

Чтобы избавится от метки ошибки воспользуйтесь функцией [clear](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/)

А чтобы вернуть указатель в начало файла функция [seekp](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/)

Вот пример кода:

```
fs.clear();
fs.seekp(0, ios::beg);
while (!numbers.empty()) {
    ....        
}
```

Так же не моё дело конечно, но заметьте, что в файл будут записаны числа в обратном порядке, если вам этого не нужно, то можете использовать структуру `vector<int> numbers;`

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать поподробнее.

Comment: @ArmanYavryan пожалуйста примите мою правку, в которой я перевел ваш вопрос (если конечно вас удовлетворяет перевод) и можете пожалуйста принять ответ если он так же вас удовлетворяет :) это делается для того, что если у кого нибудь возникнет такая же проблема, то он сразу сможет найти ответ.