# Ошибка в работе с файлами c++. Ошибка error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string file(ifstream numbers, string num_str){
    string num_str;

    numbers.open("text.txt");
    while (!numbers.eof())
    {
    getline(numbers, num_str);
    }
    return num_str;
}


int main(){
    ifstream number;
    string numb_str;

    cout << file(number, numb_str);
}
```

Comment: а что вы хотели достичь этим кодом?

Comment: что собственно вам надо вывести?

Answer (score 2):

Потоки не копируются, а здесь

```
string file(ifstream numbers, string num_str)
```

передавая поток по значению, вы именно это и пытаетесь сделать.

Передавайте поток по ссылке. Но там, где это нужно. Зачем здесь вообще передавать не открытый поток - не понимаю...

И еще - это

```
while (!numbers.eof())
```

[работает не так, как вы думаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)...

Comment: затем же зачем передавать `num_str` которая не используется ибо создается локальная версия

Comment: @Zhihar Кстати, да :) - я не обратил внимания. Какой-то странный код... "Странный, если не сказать больше" (с) :)