# Считывание неизвестного количества данных из файла

Tags: c

Есть файл, в котором записано неизвестное количество переменных(есть только верхняя граница количества), записанных в формате A1,A2,A3,...,An. Не понимаю, как занести эти переменные в массив. Пытался сделать так:

`````
while(!feof(file)){
fscanf(file,"%d",mas_name[K]);
K++;
}````
`````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Достаточно

```
while(fscanf(file,"%d",&mas_name[K++]) == 1);
```

Только массив должен быть достаточно велик.

Если числа разделены запятыми, замените `"%d"` на `"%d%*c"`.

Вот так -

```
while(!feof(file))
```

[не делайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)!

Comment: Спасибо! А можно подробнее про %*с?

Comment: Один символ, но не читать, а пропустить...

Comment: Большое спасибо!