# getline() проблема с концом строки

Tags: c++, getline

проблема такая, мне нужно показать, что строка заканчивается и на символе "," и на символе ";".

```
void read() {
        ifstream file;
        file.open("students.txt");
        if (file.is_open()) {
            cout << "Файл не считан!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            string str;
            while (!file.eof()) {
                str = "";
                getline(file, str, ',');
                cout << str << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как вам идея считать сначала всю строку,  а потом уже разделить по `,` и `;`?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Мне завтра лабу сдавать)) принимаются все варианты) как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `while (!file.eof())` - [подход неверный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну например можно написать вот так:

```
void read() {
    ifstream file;
    file.open("students.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
        cout << "Файл не считан!" << endl;
    else {
        string str;
        //Считываем весь файл
        getline(file, str, '\0');
        //strtok разделяет строку по разделителям
        char* token = strtok((char*)str.c_str(), ",;");
        while (token != nullptr) {
            cout << token << endl;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",;");
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу заметить, что у вас есть строчка `if(file.is_open())` то есть если файл открыт, то выводим `Файл не считан!`.

Comment: Да, видел Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка C4996 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` на самую первую строчку напишите

Comment: ВАУУУ,все отлично работает, спасибо!!!

Comment: подскажите еще, пожалуйста, как проверить считаный элемент, является он числом или нет?

Comment: пробовал через isdigit, не вышло

Comment: @NIkBelXD `if(символ >= '0' && символ <= '9') то символ это цифра`

Comment: Но мне же получается токен нужно проверить

Comment: @NikBelXD `token` это строка, которая была разделена разделителями `,` и `;`.

Comment: как мне тогда быть?...

Comment: @NIkBelXD я не знаю условия вашей задачи, постарайтесь сами решить проблему если не получится, то так же можете задать вопрос и вам помогут.