# file: переопределение; множественная инициализация

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream, ifstream

Пишу код, который должен вывести определенную строку из файла (text.txt), но возникает ошибка "file: переопределение; множественная инициализация" и ">>: недопустимо для class".

Код:

```
    struct element {
        char name[str_sz];
        int num, temperature;
        float viscosity;
    };
int main(){
element temp;
cout << "Введите номер строки которую хотите получить: ";
            int size, sz=0;
            string s;
            cin >> size;
            ifstream file("text.txt");
            while (!file.eof()) {
                getline(file, s);
                sz++;
            }
            file.close();
            while (size > sz) {
                cout << "Введенный номер больше чем строк в файле. Строк в файле: " << sz << endl << "Повторите ввод: ";
                cin >> size;
            }
            ifstream file("text.txt"); // тут ошибка
            if (!file.is_open())
                cout << "Не удалось открыть файл text.txt" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
                getline(file, s);
            file >> temp.name >> temp.num >> temp.temperature >> temp.viscosity; // тут ошибка
            file.close();
            cout << temp.name << " " << temp.num << " " << temp.temperature << " " << temp.viscosity << endl;
}
```

Comment: В одной области нельзя объявлять две переменные с одним именем. Или делаете вторую переменную `file` с другим именем `file2`. Или не вызывайте конструктор второй раз , а запускайте функцию `open`.

Comment: `while (!file.eof()) {` - тяжелый вздох, ссылка на то, почему так нельзя - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342 Когда исправите - поместите текст от первого `ifstream file("text.txt");` до первого же `file.close();` в фигурные скобки, и ваша проблема уйдет сама собой :)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Или просто перемотайте файл на начало вместо закрытия-открытия, нет?

Comment: Только начинаю работать с файлами, так что ещё очень мало опыта. Спасибо за информацию, почитаю, прислушаюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас два раза в одной области видимости объявлена переменная `file`.

Варианты решения. 1. Переименовать одну из переменных - скажем, `file` и `file1`.

Вариант 2 - поместить переменную в блок `{}` - тогда области видимости благополучно разрешатся.

```
cin >> size;
{
    ifstream file("text.txt");
    while (!file.eof()) {
        getline(file, s);
        sz++;
    }
}
while (size > sz) {
```

Вариант 3 - самый умный - не закрывать-открывать файл, а "перемотать" его в начало с помощью `file.seekg(0)` и работать дальше.

```
ifstream file("text.txt");
while (!file.eof()) {
    getline(file, s);
    sz++;
}
while (size > sz) {
    cout << ......;
    cin >> size;
}
file.seekg(0);
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
```

И исправьте это `while (!file.eof()) {`, а то просто глаза болят смотреть...

Answer (score 0):

В одной области нельзя объявлять две переменные с одним именем. Или делаете вторую переменную `file` с другим именем `file2`. Или не вызывайте конструктор второй раз , а запускайте функцию open.

Вторая ошибка : проверять конец файла нужно **после** попыток чтения.

```
        ifstream file("text.txt");
        while (true/*!file.eof()*/) {
            // ошибка вторая, проверку конца файла нужно делать после...
            getline(file, s);
            if(file.eof()){
                if(!s.empty())
                    sz++;
                break; }
            sz++;
        }
        file.close();
        ..
        //ifstream file("text.txt"); // тут ошибка
        file.open("text.txt");
        ..
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i){
            getline(file, s);
            // всегда нужно проверять конец файла после...
            if(file.eof())
                break; }
```