# Необходимо найти частоту появления в тексте символа и вывести с помощью контейнера map

Tags: c++, map, stl

Вроде как программу написал, но почему то частота везде равняется нулю, не могу понять в чем ошибка. Скорее всего ошибка в использовании функции count

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    /*ЧТЕНИЕ ФАЙЛА*/
    fstream in("text.txt");
    string text;
    string tmp;

    while (!in.eof())
    {
        getline(in, tmp);
        text += tmp;
    }

    ofstream out;
    /*ЧТЕНИ ФАЙЛА ЗАВЕРШЕНО*/
    /*ПРИВЕДЕНИЕ ТЕКСТА К ВЕРХНЕМУ РЕГИСТРУ*/
    transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), toupper);
    map<unsigned char, double> letterFrequency;
    int countOfSymbols = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char) text[i]))
        {
            countOfSymbols++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        letterFrequency.insert(make_pair((unsigned char)i, count(text.begin(),
                                         text.end(), (unsigned char)i) / countOfSymbols));
    }

    for (map<unsigned char, double>::iterator it =
                letterFrequency.begin(); it != letterFrequency.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну... зачем просто, если можно сложно? :)

```
int main()
{

    ifstream in("text.txt");
    char c;
    map<char,int> m;
    int total = 0;
    while(in >> c) { m[toupper(c)]++; total++; }

    for(auto k: m)
        cout << k.first << "  " << double(k.second)*100/total << "%\n";
}
```

Если надо считать и пробелы - то добавьте `in >> noskipws;` перед циклом чтения.

И еще - вот так

```
while (!in.eof())
```

[не делайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)!

Comment: Извините, вот в цикле while, что конкретно происходит? Я не совсем понимаю, как контейнер получает элемент через квадратные скобки, и как во второе значение контейнера попадает кол-во определенных символов

Comment: Это контейнер `map`, почитайте о нем. Рассказывать долго... Можно и без него, просто `int m[256] = {0};`, и приводить `c` на всякий случай (русских букв) к `unsigned char`. Впрочем, если текст только с английскими буквами - то этого будет достаточно, только при выводе надо будет смотреть и проверять элементы на ненулевые значения.