# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Си

Tags: c

Задание: Дан текстовый файл. Записать в новый текстовый файл все строки исходного файла, которые в качестве фрагмента содержат строку Str

В результате выдает ошибку - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt","r");
FILE *out = fopen("out.txt","w");
open(file);

    char str[4][100];
    char str1[100],str2[100];
    char *istr;
    int j,i;
while(!feof(file))
    for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
        fscanf(file,"%s",&str[i]);
        }

printf("Str - ");
gets(str1);
open(out);
j=1;
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
istr = strstr (str[i],str1);
if( istr!= NULL )
{
    str2[j]=str[i];
    j=j+1;
}
}
int n=j;
printf("%d",n);
for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
 fprintf(out,"\n%s",str2[j]);
close(file);
close(out);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: компилятор выдал кучу предупреждений. исправьте их сначала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понимаю, что вы вообще делаете...

```
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt","rt");
FILE *out = fopen("out.txt","wt");

char str[100];

// Чтение str допишите сами

char buf[1024]; // Максимальный размер определите сами

while(fgets(buf,1024,file))
    if (strstr(buf,str))
        fprintf(out,"%s",buf);

fclose(out);
fclose(file);
```

Этого вполне достаточно. И еще прочтите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342).