# Как найти все слова начинающиеся на гласную букву?

Tags: c++, строки, visual-studio, visual-c++

Есть задание:
Написать программу, которая считывает английский текст из файла и записывает в другой
файл те слова, которые начинаются с гласных букв.
Не понимаю как можно реализовать поиск гласной буквы в начале слова. Есть только концепция как все сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string line;

    ifstream in("D:\\gavno.txt"); // открываем файл для чтения
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(in, line))
        {
            if// Тут по идеи должно быть условие для слов на гласную
                // ну и тут дальше просто запись слова в новый файл
        }
    }
    in.close();     // закрываем файл

    cout << "End of program" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Насколько знаю, в С++ встроенных функций для определения гласности буквы нет. Т.е. простейшее, что приходит в голову, – создать вектор, вручную накидать в него все гласные, потом брать первую букву слова и проверять, есть ли она в векторе. Есть – гласная, нет – нет.

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, что такое *слово*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку точного определения, что такое слово, у вас нет, будем считать, что это просто нечто, отделенное пробельными символами (*слово в понимании потоков C++*).

Тогда проще всего заменить ваш

```
while (getline(in, line))
{
    if// Тут по идеи должно быть условие для слов на гласную
        // ну и тут дальше просто запись слова в новый файл
}
```

на чтение по словам

```
for(string word; in >> word; )
{
    if (word.find_first_of("AEIOUYaeiouy")==0)
    {
        // Записывать слово word в другой файл
    }
}
```

Как именно записывать - через пробел, каждое в свою строку и т.д. - это смотрите сами, вам виднее.

Answer (score 0):

вот я тут накалякал, но потом понял что это не сохранит пробелы и переводы строк

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<32>mask("00000001000100000100000100010001");
    //              ......zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba

    string word;
    ifstream f("in.txt");
    ofstream g("out.txt");

    while(!f.eof())
    {
        f>>word;
        if(mask[tolower(word[0],locale())-97])
            g<<word<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

не нужно переменную называть in, вроде это имя уже занято

Comment: Ну вот зачем советовать человеку неверную работу с файлом - `while(!f.eof())`?

Comment: а как? расскажите пожалуйста мне интересно как правильно

Comment: не понимаю с чего бы не правильно вроде все нормально работает и у него вообще был вопрос про гласные, а не про то как с файлами работать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Comment: спасибо буду знать