# Как найти количество всех слов конкретной длины в файле

Tags: c++, строки, текст, файловый-ввод-вывод

Слова надо брать из текстового файла данных. Необходимо определить, сколько слов текста имеют длину 1, 2, 3, …10 и более 10 символов. Вывести эти слова в последовательности возрастания их длины. Слова очередной длины вывести с новой строчки и общее их количество. После проведения всех операций необходимо занести результат в файл протокола, в котором все данные выведены в таблицу, где в одном столбце выведена длина слов, а во втором - количество слов такой длины.
Я пытался реализовать кое-что при помощи цикла for, но в консоль и протокол вместо нужных мне данных выводится зацикленный мусор такого типа: Длина слова:28 Количество слов:164

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;


void count(string FileName1, string FileName2)
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string word;
    int length = sizeof(word);
    int count = 0;
    fin.open(FileName1);
    if (!fin)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла данных" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл данных открыт успешно" << endl;
    }


    fout.open(FileName2);
    if (!fout)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла результата" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Файл результата открыт успешно" << endl;
    }


    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin>>word;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {

            if (length == i)
            {
                count++;
            }
            cout << "Длина слова:" << length << " Количество слов:" << count << endl;
            fout << "Длина слова:" << length << " Количество слов:" << count << endl;
        }

    }

}

const char* table[256] =
{
"_______________________________________________",
"|                  Строки                     |",
"|=============================================|",
"|      Длина слова    |   Количество слов     |",
"+=============================================+",
};



int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    //dash("Result.res", "Myfile.txt");
    count("Myfile.txt", "Result.res");
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще переписать логику, чем понять вашу :) - типа, находить длину слова, а потом уже его читать... Или искать его как `int length = sizeof(word);`. Все так запущено, что вот вам это:

```
int count[12]  = {0};

while (fin>>word)
{
    int len = word.size();
    if (len > 10) len = 11;
    count[len]++;
}
```

Все. По окончании работы в `count[1]` - число слов длиной 1, в ... , в `count[10]` - число слов длиной 10, в `count[11]` - число слов длиной > 10.

И еще - дайте тому, кто учил вас писать `while (!fin.eof())`... ну, в общем, что-то нехорошее... См. [Правильное использование проверки конца файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)

Comment: Мог бы сказать что-то нехорошее, если бы этот человек не был моим преподавателем, с которым очень опасно спорить

Comment: Всё выводится почти правильно, но вместо количества слов выводится 006FFA70. Также хотелось бы, чтобы все результаты выводились по возрастанию количества символов

Comment: Выводите правильно, только и всего. Вангую, что вы выводите `count` (`cout << count`), хотя я четко написал, что нужные значения - в элементах массива. Ну, а если выводить правильно, в цикле, поочередно - то вывод по возрастанию будет получен автоматически...