# при подсчете длины двузначной строки дублируется последний символ, как исправить?

Tags: c++, строки

[image: Дублируется длина, где должна быть 10 - 100, где 11 - 111]

Дублируется длина, где должна быть 10 - 100, где 11 - 111. Но с однозначными длинами все в порядке.

```
//функция обработки содержимого файла
void obrabotka_file(char* fname_i, char* fname_r)
{
    FILE* in, * out;        //исходный и результирующий файлы (потоки)
    char st_in[RAZ];        //обрабатываемая строка
    char st_out[RAZ];       //результирующая строка
    vector <char>* v;
    char* p = new char(RAZ);    //указатель на выделенное слово
    in = fopen(fname_i, PR_R);      //открываем файл на чтение
    out = fopen(fname_r, PR_W); //открываем файл на запись
    fgets(st_in, RAZ, in);      //читаем первую строку из файла in
    while (!feof(in))           //пока не найден признак конца файла
    {
        st_out[0] = '\0';           //очищаем результирующую строку
        p = strtok(st_in, " \n");   //выделяем первое слово (лексему).
        while (p)               //Пока очередное слово выделено
        {
            //обрабатываем слово
            strcat(st_out, p); //добавляем слово к результату
            string s = to_string(strlen(p));
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
                strcat(st_out, &s[j]);           
                strcat(st_out, " "); //добавляем пробел между слов
                p = strtok(NULL, " \n");        //выделение последующих слов
            
        }//while(p)
        st_out[strlen(st_out) - 1] = '\0';  //последний символ нулевой
        if (strlen(st_out))             //если строка не пустая
            fprintf(out, "%s\n", st_out);   //записываем строку в новый файл
        fgets(st_in, RAZ, in);          //считываем новую строку из файла
    }//while(!feof(in))
    fclose(in);         //Закрываем файл in
    fclose(out);            //Закрываем файл out
}
```

Comment: полнее код покажите, чтобы проверить. не видно типов переменных и т.д.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильное использование проверки конца файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: `char* p = new char(RAZ);` - память все для одной буквы.

Comment: `st_out[strlen(st_out) - 1] = '\0';` - зачем вы удаляете последнюю букву ?

Comment: удаляю последний пробел

Comment: а можно как-то более простым методом вставить длину слова за лексемой?

Comment: вот тут `strcat(st_out, &s[j]);` основная ошибка (в цикле много раз дописываете **все** символы от j-го до конца строки)

Comment: Кстати, какой формат слов вы вообще хотите получить?

Comment: главное, чтобы вывод был, как на примере в скриншоте, только с верной длиной слова

Comment: Просто используйте [sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) в цикле -- `int l = 0; while (p) {l += sprintf(st_out + l, "%s%d ", p, strlen(p)); p = strtok(NULL, " \n");}`

Comment: тогда из строки слов (111 222 333 44444) функция будет выводить в массив только последнее (444445)

Comment: @Bukashka, нет, всегда будет добавлять после уже выведенного. Вы не обратили  внимания на изменение адреса строки-приемник в цикле **l +=** sprintf(**st_out + l**, ...) (и не помните, что sprintf возвращает количество выведенных байт)

Answer (score 1):

А вы не хотите немного проще?

```
void obrabotka_file(const char* fname_i, const char* fname_r)
{
    FILE* in, * out;        //исходный и результирующий файлы (потоки)
    in = fopen(fname_i, "rt");      //открываем файл на чтение
    out = fopen(fname_r, "wt"); //открываем файл на запись

    if (!in || !out) { fprintf(stderr,"File error\n"); return; }

    for(int counter = 0, c, state = 0; (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF; fputc(c,out))
        if (isspace(c))
        {
            if (state == 1)
            {
                fprintf(out,"%d",counter);
                counter = 0;
                state = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
            state = 1;
        }
    fclose(in);         //Закрываем файл in
    fclose(out);            //Закрываем файл out
}
```