# C++. Ввод из файла, используя >> и getline()

Tags: c++, getline

Возникла такая проблема, что при считывании `std::ifstream`, используя оператор получения из потока (надеюсь, правильно назвал `>>`) и `getline()` параллельно, не получается заставить программу работать корректно.

**Main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    
    int sizeofStr = 0;
    std::ifstream fin("fileIn.txt");
    
    while (!fin.eof()) {
        fin >> sizeofStr;
        fin.ignore();
        char* str = new char[sizeofStr];
        fin.getline(str, sizeofStr);
        std::cout << str << std::endl;

        delete[] str;
    }

    return 0;
```

**fileIn.txt**

```
62
железо курит нервно в сторонке, когда этот huy думает обо мне
13
eweeweжелезо курит нервно в сторонке, когда этот huy думает обо мне
3
жцуйrtfvфывелезо курит нервно в сторонке, узщцйшзйцзшущзцушз
```

И проблема именно начиная со строки, `13` в файле.
`sizeofStr` заполняется числом `13`, всё как надо,

в переменную `str` загружаются первые `13` символов строки, как и надо,

однако, в следующей итерации, из-за того, что там дальше остаются символы, `sizeofStr` не получает значение `3`. Можно поставить в цикле после каждого `getline()` `fin.ignore()`, но тогда не будет работать итерация на первой строке, так как в ней ровно 62 символа и `fin.ignore()` проигнорирует строку со значением `13`, что нам не нужно.

Можете посоветовать, что сделать?

---

**Ред. 1**

К сожалению, по условию можно только так задавать строку. Модули по типу `<cstring>` использовать нельзя

---

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: а что мешает всегда использовать `getline`, а каждую нечетную строку переводить в число?

Comment: Или использовать `string`...

Comment: Однозначно вы  все запутали начиная от условия  цикла. и заканчивая   тем, что "fin.ignore() проигнорирует строку со значением 13"(он по умолчанию игнорирует один символ)

Comment: @Zhihar, а можешь подсказать, как строку в число переводить? Есть ли методы встроенные для этого? Или вручную надо?

Comment: @Harry, к сожалению, по условию только через массив char. Сейчас укажу в вопросе

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да, я понимаю, именно поэтому прошу помощи здесь

Comment: У вас всегда число *не больше* реальной длины строки? Такая проверка нужна?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: @Zhihar, к сожалению ```<string>``` нельзя использовать

Comment: @Harry, может быть и больше. То есть, может быть такое:

20\nabcde

Comment: Тогда сформулируйте вопрос *точно* — что должна делать ваша программа...

Comment: @DiHASTRO, есть и просто функции не из STL: `atoi`

Comment: @Harry, честно говоря, ума не приложу, что тут добавить. Суть в том, что проблема именно в этом моменте. Думаю, информации предостаточно

Comment: @Zhihar, весьма благодарен! Напишите, пожалуйста, как ответ, я укажу в качестве решения

Comment: Для меня лично — нет. Что делать, если в строке число 10, а в следующей строке 3 символа? Считывать их с `\n` вместе, дочитывать до 10 из следующей строки, не читать вообще? Задача поставлена неоднозначно и неаккуратно. Кстати, @Zhihar просто не написал, что делать в этом случае, и какого размера буфер брать для считывания строки. А у вас проблемка в том, что в вашем исходнике можно читать не более чем число символов, *на 1 меньшее, чем в числе* в предыдущей строке.

Comment: Не говоря уж о конструкции `while (!fin.eof()) {`, за которую лично я готов бить клавиатурой по голове — до такой степени часто встречается эта ошибка, что хоть пиши в комитет по стандартизации, пусть стандарт переделывают... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы решал в лоб

1. считывал бы только с помощью `getline` в строкой буфер
2. каждую нечётную строку переводил бы в число с помощью функции `atoi`

   ```
    const int value = atoi(buffer);
   ```
3. если есть возможность того, что будут пустые строки, то можно код усложнить и пытаться получить число до тех пор пока оно получено не будет, следующая выборка строки - строка, дальше опять считываем строки пока не получится число (проверяется `errno`)
4. если считывается не `char*`, а `wchar_t*`, то использовать надо функцию `_wtoi`