# Как перезаписать конкретный элемент в файле?

Tags: c++, файлы

Допустим у нас есть файл содержащий n столбцов со строками вида login password. Собственно вопрос состоит в том, как перезаписать конкретный password на n-ом столбце.
Прочитав файл таким образом я теперь могу обратиться к нужному мне password.

```
   baseusers.open(path2);

   while (!baseusers.eof())
   {
       baseusers >> log[kolp] >> passw[kolp];
       kolp++;
   }
   baseusers.close();
```

Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как присвоить ему новое значение так, чтобы оно сохранилось в файл.

P.S. Я не особо шарю в плюсах, так что не душите пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 3):

Перезаписывать в новый файл, потом переименовывать. Или считывать все в память, переделывать, как надо, перезаписывать файл...

Потому что размеры записей не фиксированы.

И еще — никогда [так не делайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342): `while (!baseusers.eof())` — будет лишняя запись.

```
while(baseusers >> log[kolp] >> passw[kolp]) kolp++;
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо) Но вот еще: через что мы перезаписываем файл? Через fstream::out | fstream::trunc ?

Comment: Если наново — я бы закрыл-открыл как новый, так проще всего :) — а то вдруг новая запись короче старой? останется мусор в конце...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало как надо)

Comment: Ну, тогда принять ответ — птичка слева от него.