# Обработать неизвестное число строк из файла СИ

Tags: c

Решаю универскую задачку и встал вопрос: а как считать из файла неизвестное число строк исключительно на языке СИ? На с++ таких проблем нет, а вот как это сделать тут?
Например, имею следующий код, который перенаправляет поток ввода из консоли в файл:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    while (true)
    {
        char buff[100];
        scanf("%s", buff);
        if (!strlen(buff))//пытаюсь таким образом определить конец файла
            break;
    }
}
```

На c++ можно остановить ввод с помощью `!file.eof()`, есть ли в данном случае сишная альтернатива? Заранее спасибо за ответ!
**UPD:** нашёл информацию о `EOF` и в си, но непонятно с чем сравнивать этот макрос в примере, чтоб понять - закончился ли файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав некоторое n-ое число статеек всё-таки нашёл способ, как отловить конец файла, используя `EOF` и `scanf`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    while (true)
    {
        char buff[100];
        if (scanf("%s", buff) == EOF)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно `!= 1` в данной ситуации лучше чем `== EOF`.

Comment: Никогда на используйте голый `%s`. Всегда добавляйте ширину: `%99s` в вашем случае.

Comment: А чем плох голый ```%s```? Извините, если глупые вопросы задаю, просто в СИ новичок.

Comment: Не контролирует запись за пределы буфера. Любая программа с этим оператором уязвима для атаки через входные данные. В лучшем случае она будет падать с ошибкой на длинных словах, в худшем делать что угодно.

Comment: Если пишете в GNU, то в [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) в формате **%s** можно использовать *optional assignment-allocation character 'm'* -- вот так -- `"%ms"`. Это  позволяет динамически выделять память и для чтения потока "по словам" можно написать: `char *buff; while (scanf("%ms", &buff) == 1) { /* do smth with new word in buff .... */ free(buff);}`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Пишу на VS!

Answer (score 1):

"На c++ можно остановить ввод с помощью `!file.eof()`" — не стоит этого делать! См. [Правильное использование проверки конца файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)

Если уж читаете построчно - просто читайте `while(fgets(buff,100,file)) { ... }`

Comment: Спасибо! Но я просил именно с использованием ```freopen``` и ```scanf``` функцией. Во всяком случае, ваш ответ натолкнул меня на решение и кажется получилось!