# Код AMI (кодирование и декодирование) работа с файлами в Си

Tags: c

пишу программную реализацию кода AMI на языке Си.
Кодирование происходит про принципу: на вход поступает последовательность символов, состоящая из нулей и единиц. Нуль всегда остаётся нулём, а единица меняется на единицу или на -единицу, взависимости от предыдущего уровня.

Необходимо написать кодер и декодер.
Я использую 3 файла input.txt -исходная последовательность, output.txt - закодированная последовательность, decoded.txt - раскодированная последовательность.

Однако, в decoded появляется один лишний нуль в конце, предполагаю, что это связано с некорректной работой feof() в данной ситуации.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main(){

int srs;
int prev_unit_level = 1;

FILE *inp, *out;

inp = fopen("input.txt","r");
out = fopen("output.txt","w");


while(!feof(inp)){


    fscanf(inp,"%d",&srs);

    if(srs == 0){
    fprintf(out,"%d ",srs);
    }

    if(srs == 1){

        fprintf(out,"%d ",prev_unit_level);
        prev_unit_level = - prev_unit_level;  

    }

}

fclose(inp);
fclose(out);


prev_unit_level = 1;

inp = fopen("output.txt","r");
out = fopen("decoded.txt","w");

while(!feof(inp)){


    fscanf(inp,"%d",&srs);

    if(srs == 0){
    fprintf(out,"%d ",srs);
    }

    else{

        fprintf(out,"%d ",prev_unit_level);
          

    }

}


return 0;


}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильное использование проверки конца файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: `while(!feof(inp)){` - это прям классический антипаттерн. Похоже, что он растет с паскаля, где это вроде работало как нужно. Вот сейчас @Harry придет и расскажет:)

Comment: Мы попадаем в состояние eof **только при очередном чтении**. Проверять `feof()` **до него нельзя**.  Реально вам надо тут написать `while (fscanf(inp,"%d",&srs) == 1) { ... }` (см. [man fscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html))