# Разделить строку на части (split)

Tags: c++

Как мне разделить строку части и вытащить оттуда 2 числа и поместить их в массив либо в 2 переменные ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void WriteRandomElemFile(ofstream &fout)
{
    int num1;
    int num2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        num1 = rand() % 100 + (-50);
        num2 = rand() % 100 + (-50);
        fout << num1 << " " << num2 << endl;
    }
    fout.close();
}

void ReadFile(ifstream &fin)
{
    if (!fin.is_open()) // если файл не открыт
        cout << "Файл не может быть открыт!\n"; // сообщить об этом
    else
    {
        string str;
        while (!fin.eof())
        {
            str = "";
            getline(fin,str);
            cout << str << endl;
        }
        fin.close(); // закрываем файл
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    ofstream fout ("input.txt");
    WriteRandomElemFile(fout);

    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ReadFile(fin);

}
```

Comment: Так читайте как два числа, а не одну строку, а потом думать, как ее делить

Comment: то есть, вместо `getline(fin,str);` пишите явно `fin >> num1 >> num2;`

Comment: У вас какой формат строки? Что в ней кроме 2-х чисел?

Comment: Это не к конкретному вопросу, а просто чтоб потом не было нового вопроса о новой ошибке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342