# Как считать две разные строки из файла в две разные переменные?

Tags: c, файлы, текстовые-файлы

Добрые день форумчанам!

Я сейчас делаю программу для формирования и обработки хэш-таблицы. Данные вводятся из файла: ключ-цифровой код, а - данные фамилия, инициалы. Типа такого:

"Добрый.А.Ю.
8347847232"

Считывание строк делаю с помощью fscanf, а нужно через fgets. Но fgets считывает всю строку целиком, и я не знаю как разделить считывание инициалов и ключа. подскажите пожалуйста, если знаете

Фрагмент кода:

```
int itemIdx = 0;
INFO* item = NULL;
HTAB* table = NewHTAB(30);
char name[MAX_NAME], key[LEN];

system("chcp 1251");
FILE* ftxt;
if (!(ftxt = fopen("RGR_2_AP.txt", "r"))) {
    puts("\n Файл не найден...\n");
    return 0;
}
while (!feof(ftxt)) {
    fscanf(ftxt, "%s%s", name, key);
    Insert(table, key, name);
}
fclose(ftxt);
```

P.S. И инициалы, и ключ считывать как строки, а не как строку и длинное число

Comment: Не понял. У вас в файле ФИО и ключ в одной строке, или, как в вопросе, в разных? ФИО не разделены пробелом (т.е. представляют собой одно слово)? Пока не будет **точного** описания входных данных, особо говорить не о чем. *"При отсутствии точного ТЗ результат ХЗ"*.

Comment: Да, вдогонку: за это — [`while (!feof(ftxt))`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342) — джунам копчик массируют :)

Comment: @Harry, по поводу первого коммента: "Да, ФИО и ключ в одной строке, и да ФИО - как одно слово".  И по поводу второго коммента: "А как тогда правильно?"

Comment: Тогда почему вам не нравится ваш способ? Чем он для вас плох? Читает же нормально, зачем обязательно `fgets`? А по второму — проверять, успешно ли считаны данные в теле цикла. Ведь вы же этого не делаете...

Comment: @Harry, он не плох, но если все так и оставить, то если в файле в самом конце будет какой-то лишний пробел или переход, у меня последняя запись в строке дублируется

Comment: Вот потому и дублируется, что `while (!feof(ftxt))`! Вы по ссылке во втором комментарии переходили? Читали? Нет? Вот она еще раз: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342 Обратите внимание на **получаются неприятности - лишняя считанная строка, например** в тексте вопроса... Кстати, замечу, что по сути вы спросили не "как правильно забить гвоздь?", а "какой рукой держать бутылку при забивании ею гвоздя?"...