# Как добавить новый элемент в вектор структуры?

Tags: c++, структуры, вектор

Задача состоит в том, что-бы реализовать каталог товаров используя при этом только структуры, а не базы данных.
Есть такая структура:

```
struct catalog
{
    string name;
    int amount;
    double price;
}; 
vector <catalog> all;
```

А вот сама функция, в которой мы сначала считываем данные из файла, а потом выводим их на экран в виде некой таблицы:

```
void items_catalog()
{
    all.resize(50);  //Данная строчка кода делает некоторый костыль
    ifstream fin("assortiment.txt");

    for (int i = 0; !fin.eof(); i++)
    {
//вот тут пытаюсь вставить all.push_back(); но он не работает
        getline(fin, all[i].name, '\t');
        fin >> all[i].price >> all[i].amount;
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << "Наименование товара" << "      " << "Стоимость товара за условную единицу" << "        " << "Остаток на складе: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << all[i].name << "                " << all[i].price << "                              " << all[i].amount << endl;
    }
}
```

Если использовать resize в качестве костыля и задать заранее в векторе запас на 50 элементов вперед, то это во-первых расточительство памяти, во-вторых при выводе каталога товаров отображаются сразу 50 строчек, поскольку выводятся и не использованные элементы, по умолчанию инициализированные нулем.

Пример текста в файле, откуда программа считывает данные в структуру:

*Говядина   90 20.0*

*Свинина    70 30.0*

*Курятина   50 40.0*

Вопрос заключается в том, как увеличивать размер вектора при каждой итерации цикла for, что-бы количество элементов в структуре четко соответствовало количество данных считываемых из файла?

Comment: 1) Чего это `push_back` не работает? А если так: `for (catalog tmp; getline(fin, tmp.name, '\t') && (fin >> tmp.amount >> tmp.price); ) all.push_back(tmp);`? 2) `!fin.eof()` [Не делайте так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980).

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось очень просто. По неопытности неправильно передавал параметры в функцию push_back.
Для того, что-бы все нормально работало стоит создать элемент структуры, в моем случае это

```
catalog temp;
```

После чего считать данные из файла в него, а уже его передавать в качестве параметра в функцию push_back.
Итоговый код выглядит так:

```
void items_catalog()
{
    vector <catalog> all;
    catalog temp;
    ifstream fin("assortiment.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open file\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; !fin.eof(); i++)
    {
        getline(fin, temp.name, '\t');
        fin >> temp.price >> temp.amount;
        all.push_back(temp);
    }
    fin.close();
    cout << "Наименование товара" << "      " << "Стоимость товара за условную единицу" << "        " << "Остаток на складе: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << all[i].name << "                " << all[i].price << "                              " << all[i].amount << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Неверное применение `!fin.eof()` — см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0