# Почему не считывает числа из файла в переменную?

Tags: c, функции, ввод

Надо для мой программы написать ввод котрый состоит из ключевого слова, а после слова будут значения, и почему то значения не вписываются в переменную, почему?
пример ввода:

```
get_c 10 457 8
```

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h >  
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #pragma warning(disable : 4996)
int proverka(char *y) {
    int com1[] = { 'g', 'e' , 't', '\_', 'c', '\0' }, com2[6] = { 'g', 'e', 't', '\_', 'a', '\0' }, com3[] = { 'l', 'c', 'g', '\0' }, com4[] = { 't','e','s','t','\0' };
        //printf("%c", y[4]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (y[i] == com1[i]) {
            if (y[4] == 'c') return 1;
            if (y[4] == 'a') return 2;
        }
        if (y[i] == com3[i]) {
            return 3;
        }
        if (y[i] == com4[i]) {
            return 4;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
    
}
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    FILE* in, *out;
    in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    char y[81], per[80];
        fscanf(in, "%s", y);
        fgets(per, 80, in);
        int i=0, flag = 0;
        while (y[i++] != 0 && i < 81) { //считывает из скольки букв состоит слово 
            flag++;
        }
        if (flag > 5 || flag <3) { 
            printf("inncorect");
        }
        else {
            //printf("%d\n", flag);
            int x = proverka(y);
            if (x == 1) { //get_c
                 long long cmax = 0, cmin = 0, m = 0;
                while (!feof(in)) {
                    fscanf(in, "%lld", &cmax); //не считывает числа которые ввожу
                    fscanf(in, "%lld", &cmin);
                    fscanf(in, "%lld", &m);
                    
                    
                }
                if ((cmin < 0) || (cmax < 0) || (m < 0)) {
                    printf("inncorect");
                    
                }
                printf("%lld %lld %lld", cmax, cmin, m);
                printf("\nyes\n");
            }
            if (x == 2) { //get_a
                            }
            if (x == 3) { //lcg
                
            }
            if (x == 4) {//test
                
            }
            if (x == -1) {
                printf("\ninncorect");
            }
        }
```

Comment: `fscanf(in, "%s", y);  fgets(per, 80, in);` — вы уже считали строку полностью, что вы еще хотите из нее считать?... Не к вопросу, но за такое `while (!feof(in))` [джунам копчик массируют](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)!

Comment: @Harry а спасибо, а можно как то считать до первого числа? 
это надо делать через цикл да?
а все поняла спасибо большое
можете написать как ответ я отмечу его

Comment: @Harry а почему за такое так.... как правильно? через EOF?

Comment: У вас идет *слово без пробелов* и три числа? Ну и читайте `fscanf(in,"%s %lld %lld %lld",y,&cmax,&cmin,&m);`

Comment: @Harry спасибо больше еще раз !

Comment: В комментарии дана ссылка, перейдите по ней и читайте...

Comment: @Harry а все поняла... спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку я с `proverka()` в комментарий не влезу, дам ответом. А поскольку ответ на незаданный вопрос плохо...

По вашему вопросу: я бы просто читал строку как

```
fscanf(in,"%s %lld %lld %lld",y,&cmax,&cmin,&m);
```

Но еще я бы переписал вашу `proverka()` — уж очень она странно выглядит...

```
int proverka(const char *y)
{
    const char * com[4] =
    {
        "get_c", "get_a", "lcg", "test"
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if (strcmp(y,com[i]) == 0) return i+1;
    return -1;
}
```

Еще — вам совсем не нужно смотреть, сколько символов считано в слово `y` — при неверном результате `proverka()` просто вернет -1. Ну и вместо длинной лесенки `if`'ов можно воспользоваться `switch-case`.

Comment: хорошо спасибо большое !