# почему c++ читает файл медленнее чем python

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод

Написал одну и ту же программу на python и c++, чтение и запись файла

На python читаю файл через `.read()` записываю `.write()`

На c++ использую `ifstream fin;` и `ofstream fout;`

```
ofstream fout;
ifstream fin;

fin.open("Path");
fout.open("Path", ofstream::app);

string str;
while (!fin.eof())
{
    fin >> str;
    fout << str << "\n";
}
```

Читаю файл построчно, подскажите как можно реализовать считывание сразу всего файла txt размером 100мб на c++, что бы я мог сразу записать содержимое в другой файл

Comment: И сработает неверно, из-за [`while (!fin.eof())`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342)...

Comment: Какой компилятор и какие флаги?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вопрос закрыт, нашёл решение

Comment: Хорошо. Но если будет похожий вопрос, эту информацию лучше сразу добавлять.

Comment: Чтение и запись в один и тот же файл. Запись на добавление. Это не должно привести к заполнению всего диска копиями содержимого файла Path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зачем именно все сразу в память? Все 100 МБайт?

Впрочем, дело ваше, как хотите.

Вот, *без проверок* для иллюстрации принципа:

```
ifstream in ("orig",ios::binary);
ofstream out("dest",ios::binary);

in.seekg(0,ios::end);
size_t sz = in.tellg();
char * buf = new char[sz];
in.seekg(0);
in.read(buf,sz);
out.write(buf,sz);
delete[] buf;
```

Но желательно все же проверки выполнять. Надежнее как-то :)

**Update**

Замеры скорости копирования на моей машине дают следующий результат для файла размером в 775 МБайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, монстрообразный буфер — это таки плохо. Можете выполнить замеры на своей машине (а главное, на своем винте :)) и найти, когда неприятности начинаются у вас...

**Update**

Код для копирования с конкретным размером буфера `bufsize`.

```
const int bufsize = 8192;
ifstream in ("orig",ios::binary);
ofstream out("dest",ios::binary);
char * buf = new char[bufsize];
unsigned int rd;
do {
    rd = in.read(buf,bufsize).gcount();
    out.write(buf,rd);
} while(rd == bufsize);
delete[] buf;
```

Comment: не спорю, с проверками лучше, просто на python эта задачы (чтение / запись) выполняется за 2-3 секунды, а на c++ при построчном чтении 16-17 секунд, я не знаю как именно происходит чтение файла в python (предполагаю что питон просто копирует содержимое файла в другой файл и все) по этому я думаю что если читать все 100мб текста сразу и их записывать, то процесс будет быстрее, если есть способ быстрого чтения и записи текста в c++ то подскажите его, я буду вам очень благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: @Robot На питоне вы читаете сразу весь файл и пишете сразу весь файл, естественно это будет быстрее, чем делать тоже самое построчно. Особенно если в питоне вы читаете и пишете в двоичном режиме.

Comment: Поблочно, но просто 100 Мбайт сразу в памяти занимать смысла особого нет. Можно обойтись какими-то более реального размера блоками; можно даже поэкспериментировать, при каком размере блока все будет достаточно быстро — поискать компромисс между используемой памятью и скоростью...

Comment: Насчет скорости — см. дополненный ответ.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за ваш полный ответ, я воспользовался тем кодом что вы указали, и скорость на с++ стала 40 сек для 2.25 Гб файлов, тогда как на python скорость 1 мин 12 сек, для тех же 2.25 Гб

Comment: А если тот код, что я добавил — для 8 КБайт? Тогда сколько времени? А для 8 МБайт?

Comment: @Harry, вы наверное в windows замеряли? Впрочем, насколько я помню свои эксперименты в linux и паре разных unix-ов, картина та же. После 128K лучше уже не становится

Comment: @avp Да, Windows. Но мне кажется, что тут дело скорее с железом связано, чем с ОС.