# Не записывается файл в массив

Tags: c++, файлы

"Прекращена работа программы", не запускается. Массив символов ch в файл file_4 записывается, открываю через блокнот. Этот же файл в массив ch2 видимо не записывается.

````
{
    char ch[] = "abc ef   g ik   l     mno p  qrst ";
    FILE* ptr_ch = fopen("file_4", "w");
    if (ptr_ch != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ch); i++) fprintf(ptr_ch, "%c", ch[i]);
        fclose(ptr_ch);
    }
    char ch2 [sizeof(ch)];
    ptr_ch = fopen("file_4", "r+");
    if (ptr_ch != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (!feof(ptr_ch))
 {
            fscanf(ptr_ch, "%c", ch2[i++]);
        }
        fclose(ptr_ch);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++) cout << ch2[i] << " ";
} ```
````

Comment: `fscanf(ptr_ch, "%c", ch2[i++]);` — и что, в `ch2[i++]` и в самом деле лежит **адрес** памяти, куда надо записывать очередной символ? А за [`while (!feof(ptr_ch))`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342), как и за отсутствие форматирования, бьют по рукам и массируют копчик.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте исправить

```
fscanf(ptr_ch, "%c", ch2[i++]);
```

на

```
fscanf(ptr_ch, "%c", &ch2[i++]);
```