# С++ Неправильно считывает данные из файла в вектор

Tags: c++, vector

Никак не могу решить проблему со считыванием файла. По задумке в вектор должны записываться целочисленные значения из файла, но при проверке того, что попало в вектор, уходит в бесконечный вывод непонятного мне числа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.(в файле цифры через пробел: 1 1 1 3 3 5 5 5 7 7 9 9 9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    
    int n;
    vector <int> SpisOchek;
    ifstream file("C:\\Morkovb.txt");
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        int n;
        file >> n;
        SpisOchek.push_back(n);
        cout << n << endl;
    }
    file.close();
    for (int i=0; i< SpisOchek.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << SpisOchek[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: кто вам учит писать !file.eof() такое условие?  И  при чем тут С++ язык, который по вашему не считывает? Язык вообще не может ничего считывать, переформулируйте заголовок. На подобные вопросы были многочисленные ответы в сайте....

Comment: `while (true) {   int n; if( not( file >> n ) ) break;...`

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас не открылся файл. Вы бы выполнили проверку того, открыт он или нет... `while (!file.eof())` тоже [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342), но не с таким эффектом. А если после последнего числа нет никаких символов, то и вовсе без эффекта :)