# При работе с текстовым файлом программа читает только первую строку

Tags: c, файлы, текстовые-файлы

задача: дан файл, содержащий некоторый текст. В новый файл записать самую длинную фразу и фразу с наибольшим количеством слов. Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define STRS 1024
#define SPACE ' '

void theLong(char* str) {
    FILE* f;/*файл*/
    int count = 0, max = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    char word[STRS] = { '\0' };
    f = fopen("new.txt", "w");
    if (!f) {
        printf("ERROR!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(f);
    for (i = j; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == SPACE)
            continue;
        count = 0;
        for (j = i; str[j] != SPACE && str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            count++;
        }
        if (max < count)
            max = count;
        i = j;
    }
    f = fopen("new.txt", "a");
        printf("ERROR!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    j = 0;
    for (i = j; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == SPACE)
            continue;
        count = 0;
        for (j = i; str[j] != SPACE && str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            word[count] = str[j];
            count++;
        }
        if (max == count)
            fprintf(f, "%s ", word);
        for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
            word[i] = '\0';
        i = j;
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    FILE* f;
    char str[STRS] = { "\0" };
    f = fopen("lab7.txt", "r");
    if (!f) {
        printf("ERROR!!!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fgets(str, STRS, f);
    fclose(f);
    theLong(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что программа читает только первую строку файлов, игнорируя что находится на следующих

Comment: Может первый fclose лишний?

Comment: Но вы же читаете только одну строку! `fgets(str, STRS, f); fclose(f);` Что же вы хотите?... Все, как вы попросили.

Comment: @Harry думал он так или иначе будет проходится по всем строкам, но получилось иначе. Как тогда переходить на след. строку файла?

Comment: Вторым таким же вызовом. Например, в цикле.

Comment: @harry типо через `while(f!=eof)`?

Comment: А вот так не стоит — см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833980/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0

Comment: @Harry добавил в тело мейна после проверки цикл `while((fread(str,STRS,1,f)==1) theLong(str)`, но ничего не происходит, компилируется без ошибок. Что-то сделано не так? как понял из интернета :1 параметр - буфер, в который будут прочитаны данные из файла, поэтому подумал, что могу использовать уже созданный массив `str`

Comment: Вы хотите считывать весь файл в один большой массив? Тогда это немного иной вопрос, чем "читает только первую строку".