# Запись из txt в массив

Tags: c++, массивы, fstream

Столкнулся с пробелом в своих знаниях, мне нужно из libary.txt содержимое записать в массив Libary
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <cstring> 

struct Book
{
    char Name[50];
    char Author[50];
    char Puplicator[50];
    char Janr[50];
};

char Libary[400];
void FillArr(std::fstream, char[]);

int main()
{

    std::fstream input("libary.txt"); // Открыли поток для чтения из файла
    setlocale(0, "");
}
void FillArr(std::fstream txt, char Libary[])
{
    Book book;
    while (!txt.eof())
    {
        txt >> book.Name >> book.Author >> book.Puplicator >> book.Janr;
    }
}
```

Вот такой "скелет" вроде как должен быть

Comment: Опять это издевательство — `while (!txt.eof())`... Что до чтения через `>>`, то учтите, что так читается только 1 (прописью: *одно*) слово.

Comment: Не особо понял что вы имеете в виду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного подумав, сделал так и все работает) Также хочу сказать спасибо всем за помощь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <cstring> 
#include <string>

struct Book
{
    std::string Name;
    std::string Author;
    std::string Puplicator;
    std::string Janr;
};
std::string filename = "расположение ФАЙЛА";
const int totalbooks = 10;
Book Libary[totalbooks];
bool ParseFile(std::string filename);
void EditBook(int, int);
char sep = ';'; // используемый разделитель 
const int num = 4; // кол-во информационных элементов в строке 

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    if (ParseFile(filename)) // загружаем и обрабатываем файл
    {
        std::cout << "Данные из файла были успешно загружены\n";

bool ParseFile(std::string filename)
{
    bool result = true;
    std::ifstream in;       // поток для чтения
    in.open(filename); // окрываем файл для чтения
    if (in.is_open()) // проверка на успешность открытия файла 
    {
        std::string line; // определяем переменную для хранения строки
        int readcounter = 0; //  кол-во обработанных строк
        while (getline(in, line)) // читаем в цикле все строки файла 
        {
            int pStart = 0; // значение индекса начала элемента 
            int pStop = 0; //  значение индекса разделителя 
            std::cout << line << std::endl; // выводим содержимое прочитанной строки
            if (sizeof(line) > 2) // проверка на минимум 3 разделителя 
            {
                Book book;
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                {
                    pStop = line.find_first_of(sep, pStart);
                    if (pStop == -1)
                        pStop = sizeof(line);

                    switch (i)
                    {
                    case 0: book.Name = line.substr(pStart, pStop - pStart);
                        break;
                    case 1: book.Author = line.substr(pStart, pStop - pStart);
                        break;
                    case 2: book.Puplicator = line.substr(pStart, pStop - pStart);
                        break;
                    case 3: book.Janr = line.substr(pStart, pStop - pStart);
                        break;
                    }

                    pStart = pStop + 1;

                }
                Libary[readcounter] = book;
                readcounter++;
            }
            if (readcounter >= totalbooks)
                break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
    }
    in.close();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

struct Book {
    char Name[50];
    char Author[50];
    char Puplicator[50];
    char Janr[50];
};

const size_t libary_size = 400; // Размера массива лучше хранить в переменной
char Libary[libary_size];


void FillArr(fstream txt, char Libary[]) {
    Book book;
}

// Эта функция вовращает поток чтения файла и может выбросить исключение,
// если файл не найден
ifstream getFileReader(const string& file_path) {
    ifstream input(file_path);

    if (!input.is_open()) {
        throw invalid_argument("FILE NOT FOUND"s);
    }
    else {
        return input;
    }
}

// Читаем файл пока не кончится файл и пока есть место в массиве
void fileReader(ifstream input) {
    size_t counter = 0;

    while(!input.eof() && counter != libary_size) {
        Libary[counter] = input.get();
        ++counter;
    }

    input.close(); // Поток чтения следует закрыть
}

// Процедура проверки результата чтения
void printLiblrary() {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < libary_size; ++index) {
        cout << Libary[index];
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    // Вставить сюда свой путь к файлу
    const string file_path = "E:/testdir/file.dat"s; 

    try {
        fileReader(getFileReader(file_path));
    }
    catch (const exception& err){
        cout << err.what() << endl;
    }
    
    // Для проверки того, что всё записалось
    printLiblrary(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И вы туда же... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342