Почему при чтении из файла while(!fin.eof()) {count++} последний символ выводится дважды, и количество символов на 1 больше чем в файле?

   #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("file.txt");
    int count = 0;
     
    int probel = 0;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        char c;
        fin.get(c);
        if (c == ' ') probel++;
        count++;
    }
    std::cout << probel << endl;
    std::cout << count << endl;

    fin.clear();
    fin.seekg(0);

  char* fromFile = new char[count+1];
    
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      char c;
      fin.get(c);
      fromFile[i] = c;
      cout << fromFile[i];
  }

    fin.close();
    delete[] fromFile;
    
}
    
}

Задача в том, чтобы считать все символы из файла в динамический массив с таким содержимым "hello, mister Bart   ". В конце есть пробелы. Перед этим считаю количество символов, чтобы узнать какую задать размерность массива.
Я понял, что !fin.eof отработает уже после того, как возникнет ошибка чтения. Это значит, что если будет строка "hi", то символы 'h' и 'i' считаются без проблем. Не могу понять, почему когда мы зайдём в третий раз, то на экран снова выведется символ 'i' и будет строка "hii"? Ведь в этой итерации пересоздаётся переменная char c; Затем мы пытаемся считать несуществующий символ fin.get(c) в переменную c, получается, в переменной с должно быть какое-то пустое значение вроде {0,-1,f}. Но VS говорит что это не так. И возникают такие вопросы:

fin.get(c) работает так, что он записывает в переменную c тот символ, который удалось считать, а если не удалось, то он записывает предыдущее. А как он знает предыдущее значение, оно записывается внутри метода или это как-то связано с самим потоком?
Правильно ли я понял, что когда мы читаем несуществующий символ (конец файла), то на весь поток накладывается fin.fail() и поэтому мы должны писать fin.clear()?
В таком динамическом массиве char тоже нужно добавлять +1 к размеру для нуль-терминатора?
Как всё-таки правильно записать в массив fromFile данные из строки? Спасибо.


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833980/195342  Да потому, что вы ничего не прочитаете, так что в c тот мусор, который в момент его создания. А поскольку эта переменная в памяти скорее всего будет там же, где и на предыдущей итерации - с чего ей менять место? - то и получите то же, что и ранее...

тут последний символ тут \n что и добавляет вам дополнительный символ.

Не понял. Если в переменной мусор, то почему fin.get(c) записал именно предыдущее значение, а не какое-то мусорное или связанное с ошибкой (0 или 1)? Переменная в памяти там же, а значение не могу понять почему прежнее.
И такой момент, в динамическом массиве тоже должен быть нуль-оператор или это уже другая структура? Имеет ли смысл ради этого добавлять [размер+1]?

Это частая ошибка https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1501631.html#post7889365
В закладки: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1260162.html

Еще раз и очень медленно, как для депутата... Переменная c имеет один и тот же адрес в памяти на каждой итерации. Т.е. в ней хранится значение с предыдущей итерации. get ничего не читает, потому что читать нечего. Значение переменной c не изменяется. Все, что делает функция — переводит состояние потока в fail. Ну а вы же не проверяете возврат функции! Вот и кажется вам, что что-то "прочитано".

Благодарю. Почему-то был уверен что строчка: char c; обнуляет переменную каждый раз + добавляет в неё мусорное значение, а не сохраняет предыдущее. Тогда всё понятно.
Максиму спасибо за полезные ссылки.

А зачем вы сначала объявляете пространство имен using namespace std;, а потом пишите std::cout.
